# Why the heck are cleated shoes called clipless?

Tags: clipless, terminology

Clipless shoes are the ones with cleats and **clips** on the pedal that the cleat **clips** into.  So why in the world are the called clipless?

Comment: Link to the Terminology community wiki [Clipless Pedals](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/245#245)

Comment: Here's a cool blog post with some vintage catalog scans. http://blog.performancebike.com/2010/05/13/flashback-friday-1987-pedals-2-0/. Also note that some of the clip-and-strap systems had cleats.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It has to do with the difference between pedals with toe clips and clipless pedals.

**Pedals with Toe Clips**

[image]

**Clipless Pedals (and shoes)**

[image]

The clipless shoes are for the clipless pedals.

The [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipless) says the following:

> Clipless refers to the lack of an
>   external toe clip, but not to
>   be confused with platform pedals
>   without toe clips.

Comment: Just to clarify, there is a bit of difference in terminology here. The 'toe clip' or 'clips' (black plastic in the first image above) should not be called a 'cage' or 'cages'. A 'cage' on a pedal is the metal surrounding the pedal body; in the above image, it is the silver part. In that sense, 'clipless' pedals are 'cageless' as well.

Comment: @Dustin, thanks, you're right - I'm removing the word 'cage' from the post.

Answer (score 1):

The confusion comes from the word "clip" being both a noun and a verb.

Clip as a noun:

1. to hold in a tight grip :  clutch
2. to clasp, fasten, or secure with a clip

This describes the old-school pedals with the leather (or vinyl) straps that strap the foot down to the pedal.

"Clip-less" pedals do not have the aforementioned securing strap.  They (obviously) use a different system.

Using "Clip" as a verb to refer to securing something (and not cutting something) is called "conversion" (linguistic term) or "verbing" (non offial term).

So, saying "*Clip* into your pedals." is similar to saying "I'm *tabling* this discussion."  It's taking a noun and converting it into a verb.

So, we cyclists confused ourselves :D