# Terminology index - a list of bike part names and cycling concepts

Tags: terminology, reference, canonical-answer, glossary

This question and its answers list the names of bike parts and cycling concepts.

### Some Rules

- Make sure you only put one term per answer!
- Try to include an image if applicable
- Include sources that contain detailed information
- Add a link to the index in this question using edit.

Also, I made this a community wiki, so that anyone will be able to edit it, and to stop rep-hoarding

---

There's a handy reference at the [Park Tool Co. website](http://www.parktool.com/), a bike repair map; it's a diagram of a bike with all the parts labeled, and is very handy! At the moment, the diagram is up at [parktool.com/blog/repair-help](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help). (They've changed the URL in the past, so this link may break.)

A road bike has the following parts ([source](http://www.jimlangley.net/wrench/wrench_images/bicycle_parts_labeled.jpg)):

[image]

A mountain bike has the following parts ([source](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8a/Bicycle_diagram-en.svg/850px-Bicycle_diagram-en.svg.png)):
[image]

---

**Edit**: This page is meant to identify what things or concepts are (as per [this thread in meta](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80/glossary-threads)). If you want to recommend an accessory or a specific product you've found handy, please use the [accessories page](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/573/whats-your-most-useful-cycle-accessory).

---

| **Contents** |  |
| --- | --- |
| **A** [Actuation Ratio](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/84691) [Axle](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/62590/32314) | [Axle Nuts](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/42804/) |
| **B** [BCD (Bolt Circle Diameter)](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/55802/32314) [Bearing](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/2758#2758) Belt Drive [Bidon/Bottle](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/64385/) [Bonk/Bonking](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/42193/) [Bottle Cage / Bottle Holder](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/13051/32314) | [Bottom Bracket](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/2759#2759) [Boom/Boom Tube](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/74190/) [Brazed Frame](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/37137/7044) [Brifter](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/6918#6918) [BSD (Bead Seat Diameter)](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/67892/38558) [BSO/Bike-Shaped-Object](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/887#887) |
| **C** [Cable Pull](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/20810/7044) [Cable Stretcher](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/667#667) [Cadence](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/451#451) [Cassette](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/82208#82208) [Chain](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/82263/48599) [Chainline](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/85714/48599) [Chain Gauge](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/2793#2793) [Chain Guard/Cover](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/21177/8) | [Chain Tool](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/3480#3480) [Chain Tug/Chain Tensioner](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/3042#3042) [Chainstay Length](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/4477#4477) [Chainsuck](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/56029/32314) [Chamois](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/5154#5154) [Clipless Pedals](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/245#245) [Coaster Brake (foot brake / pedal brake)](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/62698/32314) [Crank](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/3157#3157) |
| **D** [Derailleur](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/64473#64473) [Derailer Hanger/Derailleur Ranger](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/3665#3665) [Detangler](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/82979/19705)BMX Direct Drive Disk/Disc Brake [Disc Hub](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/4425#4425) | [Door Zone](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/1602#1602) [Dropout](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/23046/8273) [Dropper Post](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/64406#64406) [Dunlop Valve](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/1417#1417) [Dutch Bike](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/87873/19705) |
| **E** Engine/Motor | Electronic shifting Eccentric |
| **F** [Fender/Mudguard/Mudflaps](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/2803#2803) [Fixed-Gear](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/271#271) [Flip-Flop Hub](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/1982#1982) [Folding Bike](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/263#263) Fork | [Foot Peg](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/82982/19705) [Frame](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/5583#5583) [Frame Sizing](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/81667/38270) |
| **G** [Gear Inches](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/1863#1863) | [Groupset](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/7787#7787) |
| **H** [Handlebars](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/322#322) [Headset](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/10078/4239) [Hose Clamp aka Jubilee Clip](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/571#571) | [Hub](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/3404#3404) [Hub Skewer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/4478#4478) |
| **I** [Internally-Geared Hub](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/1728#1728) |  |
| **J** |  |
| **K** [Keel Tube](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/74186/) |  |
| **L** [Lawyer lips/lawyer tabs](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/5584#5584) [Lateral Tube](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/74187/) [LBS/Local Bike Shop](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/254#254) | [Lights](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/81756/) [Luggage Carrier/Rack](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/1862#1862) [Lugged Frame](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/37138/) |
| **M** [Master Link](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/4483#4483) [MIPS](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/81693/) | [Mixte](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/4539#4539) [Mountain Bike](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/13057/8) |
| **N** Noodle |  |
| **O** [Over Locknut Dimension or OLD](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/83206/48599) |  |
| **P** [Pannier](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/402#402) [P-clip or R-clip](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/88321/6852) [Play](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/58543/) [Potts Mod](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/82978/19705) BMX Brakes | [Power Meter](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/7175/8) [Presta Valve/Presta Tube](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/283#283) [Pump Peg](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/37145/) |
| **Q** [Q-Factor](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/64382/) | [Quick-Release](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/404#404) |
| **R** [Recumbent Cycles](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/81883/38270) [REI (Recreational Equipment Inc)](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/41694/32314) [Rim](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/825#825) | [Rim Tape](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/59097/24228) [Rim Brakes, e.g. cantilever, dual pivot, V-brakes](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/81822/38270) Rotor |
| **S** [Saddle](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/2812#2812) [Saddlebag](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/403#403) [Schrader Valve/ Schrader Tube](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/284#284) Shaft Drive [Single-speed](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/35893/32314) [Skewer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/4478#4478) | [Spider](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/22974/8273) [Spoke](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/13056/8) [Stack and Reach](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/83416/48599) [Stay, Mudguard/fender](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/81592/19705) [Stem](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/270#270) [Suspension Fork/Rear Shock](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/64405/38558) |
| **T** [Through/Thru Axle](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/41723/) Tire, Clincher Tire, Tubeless Tire, Tubular Tire, Solid/airless/runflat [Tire Boot](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/81940/) [Tire Clearance](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/44014/) | [Tire Lever/Tire Iron](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/1960#1960) [Tire Saver](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/22938/7044) Tire Sealant [Tolerances](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/81703/38270) [Track Pump/Floor Pump](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/2792#2792) [Triathalon Bars/Triathlon Bars](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/260#260) |
| **U** U-Brake |  |
| **V** V-Brake [Velomobile](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/81885/19705) |  |
| **W** [Welded Frame](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/37139/7044) |  |
| **X** |  |
| **Y** |  |
| **Z** |  |

Comment: One term per answer please - would be beneficial.

Comment: Is there a way to link to a specific answer, so that in future questions you can use one of these terms and link to it for reference?

Comment: Kevin: Under the bulk of the answer, there is a 'Link' hyperlink, which will link to the answer (its right above comment)

Comment: I started a discussion in meta about this thread and its twin: [Glossary threads](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/80/glossary-threads)

Comment: Whilst this is no doubt useful, it's not actually a question is it?

Comment: @MarkIngram: useful things that aren't actually questions are what community wikis are for.

Comment: This is great. I have opened a [feature request on Meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67416/glossary-dictionary-for-se-sites) in a similar vein

Comment: This page could use some more love. Maybe if people keep linking to individual terms here, more people will know about this page.

Comment: Remember to update the Table Of Contents too, if you add another answer.

Comment: @Willeke Done - yeah I agree, the table edit formatting is a mess.  Would be nice if the TOC could be generated for CWs, like latex or word can.

Answer (score 72):

## Bicycle-Shaped Object (BSO)

A derogatory term for a very cheaply produced bike with very low quality components. The components can be hard to maintain due to poor tolerances. BSOs are often sold at non-specialty retail stores.

[The etymology](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/45177/what-is-the-origin-of-bso-and-is-it-internationally-recognized) of the term is uncertain. It appears in use in some parts of the English-speaking world. It may originate in the UK, as discussed at the link. Other languages may use terms equivalent to supermarket bike or department store bike. These terms are likely to be understood in English as well.

[image: example BSO]

For instance the BSO pictured is being sold in the UK by ASDA (owned by Walmart) for £75. These bikes tend to be mass produced and sold in flat pack boxes for self-assembly.

Purchasers of lower-end bicycles tend to be less experienced cyclists who focus on price. Many BSOs carry features which are included for marketing purposes but are unnecessary for the typical end-user. Such features may include front and rear suspension, wide off-road style tyres and an excessive number of gear ratios. For cyclists who are riding on city streets or smooth trails, these features are unnecessary. Including these features reduces the budget available for better components elsewhere.

It is more advisable to search for a cheap second-hand bike in a similar price range from a more experienced cyclist or on [eBay](http://sports.shop.ebay.co.uk/Bikes-/33503/i.html?LH_TopRatedSellers=1&LH_FS=1&LH_Price=30..%40c&_trkparms=65%253A2%257C66%253A2%257C39%253A1&_catref=1&_dmpt=UK_Bikes_GL&_mPrRngCbx=1&_sc=1&_trksid=p3286.c0.m14&_sop=12&_sc=1&_qi=RTM729972) than to go for one of these.

Comment: I softened the language a bit. I agree with you about BSOs, but [the situation isn't quite that clear](http://www.bikeforums.net/showthread.php?25427-What-is-wrong-with-Wal-Mart-bikes&p=210635&viewfull=1#post210635) -- and people do occasionally tour on them. (I'll try to dig up a link for that last.)

Comment: "An impassioned guide on why not to buy a cheap Bike or BSO" http://www.southcoastbikes.co.uk/articles.asp?article=NO_BSO

Comment: Suspension - it's not just that it's unnecessary for typical users, but that cheap suspension will add weight and absorb pedalling energy for little or no benefit. (An unpractised rider on pot-holed roads may well benefit from wide tyres though, if not knobbly ones).
Also, the typical bike shaped object is heavy, being cheap steel tubes which are both large (to imitate the look of better aluminium frames) and thick-walled (to compensate for cheap steel with cheap welding being weaker). The one illustrated is far from the worst available.

Answer (score 50):

### Door Zone

The area next to parked cars that a suddenly opened door would cover.  A hazard that you should avoid.

[image]

*Satirical portrayal of Santa Monica bike lane design; it illustrates the "door zone" concept well.*

Cycling in the Door Zone reduces your ability to react to hazards emerging from the space between parked vehicles. These may include unobservant pedestrians, inadequately restrained dogs (whose leads can reduce your options), sports equipment and children chasing sports equipment.

Drivers entering the road from a driveway, forecourt or junction are less likely to observe a cyclist who is not occupying the space where oncoming motor vehicles are expected to be observed. This contributes to the SMIDSY(*Sorry mate, I didn't see you*) phenomenon.

Comment: I've never seen this before in the UK. Interesting.

Comment: @Amb100: you've never seen a bike lane that ran through the area doors would open into? The "DOOR LANE" thing isn't real, but the configuration of bike lane in door zone is common in the US.

Comment: Oh I see. I thought it was a good idea.

Comment: Also known as the death zone.  As a rider goes slower, they're more likely to be riding closer to the kerb and parked cars.  Faster riders tend to move out more and into the traffic lane.

Answer (score 49):

### LBS

[LBS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_bike_shop) is the acronym commonly used for **L**ocal **B**ike **S**hop. The term is usually used when comparing small, privately owned shops with big box or department stores, or with internet-based bicycle retailers. In the UK and Ireland, the expression **I**ndependent **B**icycle **D**ealer (IBD) is also used.

The best local bike shops usually have trained staff who have many years of experience in selling, maintaining, and repairing bicycles and have a well-equipped repair workshop. They can special order parts and let you know if a modification you want to make will work -- and how to make it work. They also can serve as hubs for the local cycling community, connecting riders to other riders. As with all things, local bike shops vary in terms of their experience and attitude. It pays to shop around to find a LBS that matches your interests and orientation, e.g. more casual cyclist, touring cyclists, competitive cyclists.

Large department or chain stores, on the other hand, often sell low-quality bikes (aka [BSOs](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/887#887)). Their staff usually have little to no background in bicycle mechanics. Thus, they may not properly assemble the bikes, and they usually cannot repair or maintain the BSOs they do sell because they do not have the skills to do so. Your only recourse may be to just return the whole bicycle to the store if it is still under warranty.

Internet bicycle retailers often have lower prices than LBSes due to economies of scale. However, it is harder to get service and support there.

[image: http://www.flickr.com/photos/johnprolly/5728618798/]
http://www.flickr.com/photos/johnprolly/5728618798/

Answer (score 49):

### Presta Valve / Presta Tube

**aka Sclaverand valve (SV) or French valve**

[image]

The Presta valve is a valve commonly found in high pressure road style and many mountain bicycle inner tubes. The air pressure in an inflated tire holds the inner valve body shut. A small screw and captive nut on the top of the valve body permits the valve to be screwed shut and ensure that it remains tightly closed. The nut must be unscrewed to permit airflow in either direction (this must be done before attaching a pump). The screw remains captive on the valve body even when unscrewed fully; it is tightened again after the tire is inflated and the pump removed.

[image: Presta valve]
[photo credit](http://www.flickr.com/photos/becw/444566898/)

Photo sequence of removing the dust cap then unscrewing the nut so the valve is ready to inflate.

A Presta valve adapter can be used to fill a Presta tube with a normal [Schrader-style](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/284#284) air pump, although many pumps today come with a built-in adapter.

[image]

For a video tutorial on the use of the adapter, [check out this video at BicycleTutor.com](http://bicycletutor.com/presta-valve/)

More information: [Presta valve (Wikipedia).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presta_valve)

Go to [Schrader valve](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/284#284).
Go to [Dunlop valve](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/1417#1417).

Answer (score 44):

### Cadence

Cadence is the number of revolutions of the crank per minute.

> Cyclists typically have a preferred cadence at which they feel most comfortable, and on bicycles with many gears it is possible to stick to a favourite cadence at a wide range of speeds. Recreational and utility cyclists typically cycle around 60–80 rpm; racing cyclists around 80–120 rpm and sprinters up to 170 rpm for short bursts. The professional racing cyclist and Tour de France champion Lance Armstrong is known for his technique of keeping up high cadences of around 110 rpm for hours on end to improve efficiency<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadence_(cycling)

If you are getting pain in your knees, it could be that your cadence is too low. A cadence between 80-100 will probably reduce knee pains, as [stated in bicycling.com](http://www.bicycling.com/training-nutrition/injury-prevention/knock-out-knee-pain) or [more detailed at Cycling Performance Tips web site](http://www.cptips.com/knee.htm).

**EDIT by Ivor**

To answer a comment below on beginners and cadence...

Cadence is critical to enjoying your cycling and if you become involved in cycle racing, winning. Cadence is something that is learned and once learned you promptly forget about it and move onto getting other things right :)

For a beginner:

1. Get to know your gears.

   - Drop it into a high gear (big chainring on the front, small cog on the back)
   - Feel how hard it is to push (Pay attention to where you feel the muscles working)
   - Drop it into a low gear (smallest chainring on the front, largest cog on the back)
   - Feel how free your legs spin (Pay attention to how you bounce in the saddle :)  If you are bouncing, then you are spinning too much, i.e. your cadence is too high)
   - Find a combination of gears that allow you to spin your pedals without feeling undue pain in your muscles and doesn't make you feel out of breath. (Ignore the speed for the moment)
   - Get to know this "sweet spot", ride around in this gear for a while and adjust your gears to suit your speed so that you balance not being out of breath and over exertion. (Watch out for the bounce in the saddle :) )
2. The next thing to take into account is how fast you want to go

   - Without a bike computer? - Your feeling of relative speed is good enough
   - With a bike computer? - Set a reasonable target, say 20 km/h
   - Using the gears you have selected for your sweet spot, try to hit your target speed.
   - Once you hit it, can you keep it going? For how long? - Set a reasonable target say 5 mins.
   - When you have finished this, where does it hurt?
   - In your chest? Out of breath big time? - You may have been spinning too much, i.e. your cadence was too high?
   - Muscles in the small of your back, quads, glutes, knees, calves groaning or hurting (not burning, burning isn't as bad as you think) - You may have been spinning too little i.e. your cadence was too low?
3. There is an ideal cadence proposed by some sports physiologists that is somewhere between 80 to 100 turns of the pedal per minute (rpm)

   - The only way to know your cadence accurately is to have a cadence enabled bike computer and sensor.
   - The other way is to know your gear ratios ([Check out BikeCalc.com](http://www.bikecalc.com/cadence_at_speed))
   - For example, You are riding your bike, it has a wheel of size 700c/29 and a tyre that is 23 mm wide,  with a front chainring of 34 teeth, a rear cog of 17 and you are pedalling at a speed of 20 km/h. You should then have a cadence of 79 rpm. Simples :) (Get the bike computer ;) )
4. Get used to spinning your legs in that range of RPM, i.e. 80 to 100 rpm.

   - In all conditions, on any terrain, whatever the occasion.
   - It trains your heart and body to be cardio fit and with a stronger heart comes better stamina and greater strength.
   - Pick up the pace and work to get the legs spinning at the next level of speed.
   - Hard work and worth it.
5. Go cycling with a group more experienced than you

   - Watch them as they cycle, see all of the different styles and high cadence
   - Listen to the experienced guys as they can advise on many many things.
6. Enjoy it, you will have earned it :)

Comment: We're really not here to copy and paste from Wikipedia. Are there recommended cadence rates for beginners? What users are generally concerned with cadence? Perhaps you could address concerns like these?

Comment: I'm not sure that citing Lance Armstrong as an example is really useful, given that he achieved his performances through doping...

Comment: @Ivor my reading of your edit is that it's not clear if bouncing on the saddle is good or not. Can you make that clear please?

Comment: @andy256 I have taken your comments on board and modified the edit. Bouncing is definitely not good. The Quote I used to differentiate the text and have now removed it as the text is my own ramblings on cadence and I am the only one who would claim it :)

Answer (score 43):

### Clipless pedals a.k.a. clip-in or step-in pedals

Clipless pedals require a special cleated cycling shoe that locks itself into the pedal's surface. To release a foot/shoe from a clipless pedal, the rider typically twists his/her foot outwards. These were inspired by ski bindings.

Before clipless pedals, riders used rigid shoes with flat (also called quill) pedals and toe clip straps, as pictured below. The term "clipless" refers to not needing the toe clips. However, it is confusing because riders "clip in" to the pedals. Alternatively, flat pedals are an option for riders not willing to use clipless pedals or toe clips. On MTBs, flat pedals typically have retaining pins for grip.

[image: pedal with toe clip and strap]

A clipless pedal was patented as early as 1895 by Charles Hanson, as documented on Wikipedia's [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipless_pedals#Clipless_pedals) on clipless pedals. Speedplay, a relatively niche pedal maker that is relatively popular in triathlon, maintained an online museum that was taken down since its acquisition by Wahoo. [They contend that](https://web.archive.org/web/20131021223203/http://www.speedplay.com/index.cfm?fuseaction=pedalmuseum.clipless) (link to archive.org) Cinelli may have released what Speedplay called "the first modern-day clipless pedal" in 1970. Look, a French company that manufactures road bikes and components, may have been the first to release a widely recognized and adopted pedal system. [Their corporate history](https://www.lookcycle.com/us-en/inside/about-look-heritage) contends that they developed ski bindings, and translated that system to road cycling. Wikipedia documents that Bernard Hinault won the Tour de France in 1985 on Look pedals. An example of LOOK pedals is below.

[image: LOOK Pedals]

LOOK pedals came first and were inspired by ski bindings.  LOOK pedals are commonly used on road bikes. A similar (but incompatible) pedal system is Shimano's SPD-SL system.

Subsequently, Shimano appear to have adapted clipless pedals to mountain bikes. Notably, MTB shoes have tread, and MTB pedals have generally developed to be able to clear dirt and mud. Cycling shoes are compatible either with road (3 bolt mounting system) or MTB shoes (2 bolt mounting system), although a handful are compatible with either.

[image: Shimano SPD]

There are multiple companies manufacturing road and MTB pedals. Road cyclists often perceive that road pedals offer a bigger and more stable platform than MTB pedals. MTB pedals and shoes are objectively easier to walk in. There is nothing wrong with choosing to use MTB pedals on a road bike. In the reverse case, road pedals are often unable to engage if contaminated by dirt or mud.

### Concepts

- You need to choose a *fore-aft* position for the cleats. It is common practice to start with the cleats under the ball of the foot. Some riders prefer to have their cleats further back than this. [Rearward positions may be better](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/55979/pedal-foot-position-balls-or-arches/55983#55983) for endurance riders or long slow distance rides. Some sprinters may prefer their cleats further forward. All shoes have some range of fore-aft adjustment, although some makes may have less adjustment than others.
- Most cleats have *float*, I.e. you can rotate your heel left or right, usually by a total of about 2-3 degrees in each direction. This accounts for the fact that we tend not to point our feet straight ahead. For road shoes especially, you can rotate the cleats to account for this. There are guides on how to do this on YouTube, but a bike store will be able to help you. If you feel like you want to rotate your foot further but it is at the limit of the pedal, you should seek help.
- Some cleats have zero float or very low float (e.g. black LOOK and red Shimano SPD-SL cleats). Most casual cyclists should avoid these. If you decide otherwise, you need to pay attention to cleat rotation to avoid knee problems.
- Cleats will wear and require periodic replacement. Highly active riders might replace them yearly, maybe more. Rubber cleat covers can help reduce wear while you’re walking on road cleats. However, clipping and unclipping does wear the cleat. If your cleats are worn, it will feel like the pedal is gripping your shoe sloppily, and there may be [play](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/58543/) in unexpected directions (e.g. up/down). The picture below is from Shimano’s SPD-SL cleat manual and shows the wear indicators in the cleat.

[image]

Comment: Aren't TIME pedals kind of major? I see a lot of them (and I own a pair), but it might be some kind of local phenomenon...

Comment: @domsterr: Feel free to edit this answer

Comment: Added a link to clip+strap pedals, mainly to explain why clipless pedals have clips!

Comment: Would platform pedals qualify as well, since they are 'clipless' too?

Comment: I don't have the ability to edit (or the knowledge) but I'd encourage a bit of expansion here with shoes/cleats. See: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/20700/im-a-bit-confused-on-bike-shoe-terminology-particularly-regarding-look-keo-plu

Comment: @DecSim good catch on the crankbrothers/spd compatibility

Comment: Is "lollypop" as shorthand for the Speedplay pedals a common thing, or just in my circles?

Comment: @Michael "Lollypop" is a Speedplay nickname I have heard, but it's not that common, at least in the parts of the US where I've lived. To all: aside from pedals of historical interest like Look and Shimano SPD (or whoever was the 1st MTB pedal), do we want to have specific examples here given that we don't make product recommendations? You could validly ask why not TIME road or TIME ATAC MTB pedals, and if yes to those, why not Keywin road, etc.

Comment: In that case, consistent with what was done on the power meter and suspension articles, I'm removing the specific examples here. I do retain a reference to Look because I believe they were the first widely accepted and commercially available road clipless pedal.

Answer (score 36):

### Fixed Gear or Fixed Wheel

#### AKA: Fixie

A fixed-gear bicycle has the rear gear locked to the hub, which fixes the pedals rotation to the rear wheels rotation. In other words, you can't coast; the pedals are always in motion as long as the bike is.  Track bikes are commonly fixed-gear.

The sprocket is screwed directly onto a fixed hub. When the rear wheel turns, the pedals turn in the same direction. This allows a cyclist to stop without using a brake, by resisting the rotation of the cranks, and also to ride in reverse.

Fixed-gear bikes are almost always single-speed (i.e. have only a single gear ratio), but internal-gear hubs without freewheels do exist.

[image: flip-flop hub on fixie setting]

The hub in the picture is a [flip-flop hub](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/1982#1982).

More information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_gear

Compare with [Single Speed](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/35893/8273).

Comment: One should note that typically, horizontal dropouts are required to convert a bike from derailleur to fixed gear, since a pulley cannot be used as a chain tensioner (when you resist to brake, the pulley will be sheared off the bike). Vertical dropouts can be adopted in some cases using something like White Industries' Eccentric Rear Hub or an eccentric bottom bracket or something.

Answer (score 33):

### Schrader valve/Schrader tube

#### aka "American valve" or "car valve" or "Auto valve" (AV)

[image]

The Schrader valve consists of a valve stem into which a valve core is threaded, and is used on virtually all automobile tires and most wider rimmed bicycle tires. The valve core is a poppet valve assisted by a spring.

A valve cap is important on a Schrader valve because if one is not fitted, dirt and water can enter the outside of the valve, potentially jamming it or contaminating the sealing surfaces and causing a leak. Rock salt and other chemical deicers used in the winter are especially damaging for the brass components in the Schrader valve.

Schrader valves are almost universal on car tires, meaning you can often (carefully) inflate your bike tires with the air machines at roadside garages.

For an instruction video on patching and inflating a Schrader tube, [check out this video on BicycleTutor.com](http://bicycletutor.com/fix-flat-tire/).

More information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schrader_valve
Go to [Presta Valve](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/283#283).
Go to [Dunlop valve](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/1417#1417).

Comment: I don't think it would hurt to combine this one with its sibling answer

Comment: @Joe - Except that it makes linking to one valve or the other more difficult.

Comment: In the UK at least this can also be referred to as the 'car type' since it's common to our car tyres.  It's quite useful to use this type of valve because it means you can get your tires pumped up at petrol stations.

Comment: What are the advantages/disadvantages of this type of valves? Do they loose more air with time? (compared to presta) Are they heavier? Easier to find pumps for it?

Answer (score 31):

### Pannier

A pannier, pronounced [*pan-yer*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/media/british/us_pron/e/eus/eus75/eus75855.mp3) /ˈpanyər, ˈpanēər/ (US) or [*pan-i-er*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/media/british/uk_pron/u/ukp/ukpam/ukpampe028.mp3) /ˈpanɪə/
(UK) <sup>[[1](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/pannier?q=pannier)]</sup>, is a bag designed to be mounted on the side of a [bicycle rack](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/1862#1862). Bags can be made of nylon, canvas, or waterproof materials such as PVC. Panniers are most commonly carried on the rear, but smaller panniers intended for a front rack are also available.

[image]

Often erroneously called a saddlebag because a [pannier on a motorcycle or horse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddlebag) is attached to the saddle. On a bicycle, the [saddlebag](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/403#403) mounts behind the rider from loops at the back of the saddle. The saddle bag goes athwartship – from side to side.

Bikes that do not have rack mounts can often accept bags that strap under the handlebars, under the top tube, and behind the seatpost. Gravel bikes often do not have rack mounts, and these alternative bags are used instead. Potentially, these may affect a bike's handling more than a rack and panniers would, because the loads are carried higher on the bike.

Comment: How do you pronounce this? pan-near, panny-air, pan-near?

Comment: I pronounce it pan-yay, but I'm not sure how to *properly* say it.

Comment: It's an English word that's commonly mistaken for being a french word.  It's pronounced "PAN-yer", but many people say "PAN-yay".

Comment: @freiheit - The link you put in allows for two pronunciations, I updated this entry.

Comment: @JasonS - We should update the answer with these comments. Any idea how to phonetically represent those pronunciations? We should have Australian/NZ phonetics as well.

Comment: @freiheit: It's an English word that *is also* a French word. That's like saying "Paris" is an English word that's commonly mistaken for a French word. In English, we pronounce "pannier" as "PAN-yer" and "Paris" as "PAIR-iss" but in French they are pronounced "Pan-YAY" and "Pa-REE."

Comment: @R.Chung: Yes, but it means something somewhat different in French. A lot of English words originated as French words, due to that whole Norman invasion and conquest back around 1066... Pretty sure that [Paris, Illinois](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris,_Illinois) is not pronounced "Paree", for instance.

Answer (score 31):

### Flip-Flop Hub

Most often seen on [fixed gear](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/271#271) track (velodrome) bikes, a flip flop hub is hub that allows a cog to be attached to each side.

This allows a rider of a [fixed gear](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/271#271) bike to effectively 'change' gears by taking the rear wheel off, flipping it around and reattaching the wheel.

Track riders will use this to have a smaller (more teeth, fewer [gear inches](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/1863#1863)) warmup gear that allows them to spin at a higher cadence and a larger (fewer teeth, more [gear inches](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/1863#1863)) cog for racing or high speed efforts.

Variations of flip-flop hubs might offer a freewheel in one direction and a fixed gear in the other, so a cyclist can convert the bike from a single-speed to a fixed gear bike by flipping the rear wheel around.

The unused cog is an additional hazard. Many velodromes require unused cogs to be removed. A collision involving a bike carrying an unused cog at the 2013 North America Harcourt Bicycle Polo Championships led to an amendment of the NAH ruleset to explicitly identify exposed unused cogs as a prohibited hazard. Players are permitted to carry an unused cog if it is covered.

For a fixed-gear road cyclist, a flip-flop hub often is used to allow one side as a fixed gear, and the other side to freewheel. This way, a tired fixie rider can switch to freewheeling (possibly with a different ratio) and get home.

More information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_hub

[image]

Answer (score 30):

### Quick-release

Quick release skewers (sometimes abbreviated QR, sometimes just called skewers) secure bicycle wheels in the dropouts. They have a lever that when opened, enables the wheel to be removed quickly and without additional tools. They use a cam mechanism at the lever end pulling against a threaded nut at the other end. The [cam mechanism](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/skewers.html) may be internal or external; the latter type is cheaper to produce and is often lighter, but it produces lower clamping force for the same amount of hand pressure on the QR lever.

Wheels with disc brakes may be secured by QRs or by [thru axles](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/41723#41723). Disc brakes generate a lot of torque at the hub. [Some experts contend](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/disc-brakes.html) that disc brakes can eject wheels from dropouts. Thus, most current disc brake bikes and wheels use thru axles.

If you are replacing a quick release, you may need to take note of the length of the rear QR. Mountain bike hubs for quick releases have had a length of 135mm over the locknuts, compared to road hubs’ 130mm. If a QR is road specific, it may be listed as 130mm. An MTB QR can be used on a road rear hub. It will have a bit of extra axle protruding, but this does not interfere with anything. If a QR is simply listed as “rear”, it is probably suitable for MTBs. Front road and MTB QRs are 100mm long.

[image: a picture of a bicycle front wheel quick release assembly]

<sub>[Quick-release axle](http://www.flickr.com/photos/billjank/25358685/in/photostream/) (internal cam)</sub>

#### Miscellany

Their invention is frequently attributed to Tullio Campagnolo, the founder of the eponymous component manufacturer. Jan Heine's research shows this [may be inaccurate](https://janheine.wordpress.com/2014/07/01/a-reappraisal-of-tullio-campagnolo/). Heine was unable to determine who invented the QR, as there appears to be no original patent for the QR mechanism. Campagnolo was certainly one of the first companies to mass produce a high-quality QR.

Tabs called [lawyer lips](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/gloss_l.html) frequently come on fork and/or frame dropouts. They prevent the wheel from dropping out immediately when the QR lever comes open, the nut must be unthreaded several turns as well. These tabs increase the amount of time needed to operate a QR but they can be an important safeguard against improper operation of a QR.

QRs [are sometimes used](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/skewers.html) on seatpost clamps as well, to allow easy adjustment of the saddle height. "Quick-release" also refers to several other types of quick-release mechanisms that are popular on [folding bicycles](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/263#263), such as collapsible seatposts and folding frames.

Last, *non*-quick release skewers exist, often for security purposes. These are loosened on one side with hex wrenches or similar implements. They are similar to [axle nuts](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/42804#42804).

Comment: I know there are some different kinds of quick release. Some have a spring in there to make it easier right? Maybe explain those differences

Comment: The quickness of the release is defeated on most bikes by extra lugs that force you to unscrew the axle almost fully to remove the wheel.  They are supposed to stop the wheel falling out if the release comes loose - but they are really to stop you sueing and so are called lawyer-lugs

Comment: @Martin - I think the value of a quick release isn't that it's fast so much as that you don't need a wrench to get the wheel off.

Comment: Well, Tullio Campagnolo's design (which forms the basis of a modern QR skewer) was designed for race conditions, so the speed value exists. I've never heard lawyer lugs, but I have heard lawyer lips. In most cases, however, the primary value is the lack of tools (which does make it relatively faster).

Comment: and of course in cities like NY you don't want to have a quick release on your wheels because they will get stolen.

Answer (score 28):

### Triathlon bars or Aerobars

Aerodynamic handlebars are used extensively on triathlon, time trial, and track bikes, and sometimes in long-distance racing or riding on the road. The position on the extensions reduces the rider's frontal area considerably.

The picture below shows a full aerodynamic bar setup used on a dedicated bike. Shifters are mounted on the extensions, and brake levers on the base bar. One can also buy clip-on bars for standard road bikes. This type of bar would also be used in draft-legal triathlon races.

They are illegal in mass start road races because the aerodynanmic position has the rider's hands away from brakes, and the narrower arm stance makes the rider slightly more unstable on the bike. These factors reduce control.

[image]

Sources:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_handlebar#Triathlon_or_aero
- http://www.beginnertriathlete.com/cms/article-detail.asp?articleid=1414

Comment: Are tri-bars purely aerodynamic or do they adjust your riding position enough to relieve muscles you will use in the run part of a triathlon?

Comment: Remember Greg Lemond final time trail in the Tour de France 1989. Closest TDF win ever! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AyvwtOQYQ-E Thank you earobars.

Comment: @mgb It might be that triathlon bikes in general are designed for a more forward position (steeper seat angle). This is thought to make you use your hamstrings more, whereas you may need your quads for the run. I'm not sure if that contention is backed up by research! https://forum.slowtwitch.com/forum/Slowtwitch_Forums_C1/Triathlon_Forum_F1/How_much_Tri_Bike_save_your_legs_for_Run_P3931240/

Answer (score 23):

### Stem

Attaches the handlebars to the bike, or, more precisely, to the steerer tube. Stems are designed differently for different [headset types](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/10078/4239) (i.e. threaded or threadless). They are also sized to suit different diameter handlebars and in the case of threadless setups, different diameter steerer tubes.

Stems play a key role in setting your riding position. You can adjust the reach to the handlebars by changing the stem's length. Separately, you can move the stem vertically to change your riding position. Stems for road bikes typically come in lengths ranging from 80 to 140mm. Mountain bikes have moved to significantly shorter stems than this. If you need a stem much shorter than 80mm on a road bike, that is a sign the bike doesn't fit you. All else equal, a shorter stem will make for quicker handling. If you are buying a new bike and you know you need a different stem length, the bike store should be willing to trade your stem for something they have in stock.

Another characteristic of stems is their angle. Threadless stems commonly come in angles around -10 degrees, sometimes more. You can flip a threadless stem so that it increases the height of the bar. There are also angle-adjustable stems made, so the rider may change bar positions without removing the handlebars or changing the stem, although their length typically can't be adjusted. An adjustable stem is shown below.

[More information at Sheldon Brown's site](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/gloss_st-z.html#stem)

[image: Adjustable stem]

[Adjustable stem on a touring bike, attached to the headset with risers, with the handlebars removed](http://www.flickr.com/photos/neilfein/4152225798/)

---

The picture below shows several threadless stems of various lengths. All have *spacers* under the stem. New bikes come with the steerer tube uncut and a number of spacers, up to 40mm (or more), made in 5mm or 10mm increments. It is common to cut off the excess steerer tube above the stem after you finalize your position. However, you can leave some spacers above the stem, as in the top right picture. In fact, it is advisable to, in case your position changes or you sell the bike.

[image: https://cdn.road.cc/sites/default/files/styles/schema_org/public/how-choose-right-stem-length-august-2018.jpg]

The picture below shows some threaded stems (also called quill stems). They are shaped like a number **7**. The expanding wedge on the bottom of the stem secures the stem inside the steerer tube, and it is activated by the binder bolt on the top of the stem. The stem threads into the steerer tube. Threaded stems have some inherent vertical adjustment available, although be cautious of the maximum and minimum insertion marks.

It is common for threaded stems not to have a removable faceplate, whereas this is rare for threadless stems.

[image: https://cimg8.ibsrv.net/gimg/bikeforums.net-vbulletin/640x480/800524cb_624a_4332_9c47_32c7e3c939c2_e0fc0d038e37e9ff273792d066cd19a8f038d413.jpeg]

This folding bike effectively has a stem of nearly zero length.

[image: https://www.actionbicycleclub.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/brompton_pink.jpg]

Comment: Not to be confused with a valve stem.

Comment: This might need a section on Stem Cap and Stem Spacers - too small for their own section but are absolutely related to stems.

Answer (score 23):

## Dunlop Valve

### aka Woods valve or English valve

The Dunlop valve is an older style valve that is no longer commonly found in the english speaking world. It is still commonly found in Japan, Germany, and the Netherlands on non-speciality bicycles. The advantage of a Dunlop valve is that it is very easy to manufacture. The main pressure control mechanism is a simple rubber tube called a "plug" or "worm" that can be easily replaced. However, the rubber plugs also quickly degrade and this can be a cause of frustration for users. Recent Dunlop valves in Japan come with mechanical springs rather than plugs.

A pump designed for a Presta valve can be used to fill a tube with a Dunlop valve.

Modern versions of this valve use a different method to keep the air in, a small ball in the valve and a rubber ring that does not stop the air flowing in. These hardly ever fail in use but can get stuck if not pumped in a long time.

[image: Dunlop Valve]

More information: [Dunlop valve (Wikipedia).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunlop_valve)

Go to [Presta valve](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/283#283).
Go to [Schrader valve](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/284#284).

Also see [this answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1414/whats-the-rubber-tube-in-my-puncture-repair-kit-for/1416#1416).

Comment: This is the most common valve on everyday usage bicycles in The Netherlands

Comment: and possibly here in Poland too

Comment: And Japan, almost all non specialty bikes are Dunlop valves.

Comment: Very common also in Germany. We distinguish the interior: rubber plug vs. "Blitzventil" (flash valve): Rubber plugs are notoriously hard to pump because there's a lot of pressure lost at the plug, the Blitzventil has a ball valve which works basically without any pressure loss.

Answer (score 23):

### Tire Lever

#### aka Tire Iron

A tire lever is a small, narrow lever used to help lift a tire off a rim. Traditionally they were steel, later aluminium alloy and now most commonly they are plastic. The hook on the right side of both the levers below can go around a spoke to hold one lever in place while you use a second lever on a different section of tire. The left end is used on the tire bead.

The most important feature of a tire lever is that it does not have any sharp edges that may "pinch" the tube (that is, become wedged between the tube and the tire) causing a small hole or tear in the tube.
Operation of tire levers usually involves either a pair or a triple set of levers. Levers can also be used help get a tire onto a rim when it is a particularly tight fit.

[image: Plastic & Alloy tire levers]

More information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tire_iron

Comment: Is it possible to use the metal irons with anodized rims without damaging the coating? I bought some cheap ones, and they're ribbed on the face, and a bit sharp on the edge of the face, and when they slip, they dig in to the rim a bit.

Comment: and a question here: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/17743/metal-or-plastic-levers/17776

Comment: IIRC, the plastic ones were (decades ago) also called "milk levers" because the original plastic ones were made out of recycled plastic milk containers (or so the story went).

Answer (score 20):

### Chain Tool or Chain Breaker

[image]

Used to 'break' a chain by punching out one of the link pins. Needed to shorten a new chain to the correct length or to replace a broken link.

A chain link is placed in the open slot and the handle turned to force a punch pin into the pin of the chain, pushing it out of the other side.

Traditionally the tool needed to be used quite carefully such that the pin would not pushed all the way out, as the same pin was later used to reassemble the chain, using the same tool.  Obviously, if a chain is repeatedly "broken" and reassembled this way at the same link the pin and associated holes in the plates will wear and no longer hold well, so care must be taken to not do this.

More recently this strategy has changed somewhat.  Shimano now supplies special replacement pins which are equipped with a break-off guide cone on one end, making it easier to reassemble the chain.  (Even with this scheme one should still avoid repeatedly "breaking" and reassembling the chain at the same link, though.)

Several other manufacturers now sell what is commonly called a [master link (or quick link)](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/4483#4483), which allows a chain to be reassembled without tools when new and clean.

[image]

Fingers are usually too weak for the worn chain, and another specialized tool, chain pliers ([image credit](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Master_link_pliers.jpg)), is then used to disconnect or connect the master link:

[image]

Comment: Rohloff call this a "[chain riveting tool](https://www.rohloff.de/en/products/tools/)"

Answer (score 20):

### Derailleur hanger

Rear derailleurs bolt to a hangar beside the right rear dropout. As in the pictures below, most derailleur hangers are separate pieces of metal, usually aluminum, that bolt onto the dropout. These are called replaceable derailleur hangers.

[image: Replaceable derailleur hanger] [image: derailleur hanger 2]

Derailleur hangers frequently bend slightly if a bike is dropped or crashes, which is especially common off road. This can compromise shifting. However, the advantage for replaceable hangars is that they bend and break before the derailleur or the frame. The hanger can then be bent back or replaced. Replaceable hangers are proprietary to each frame and tend not to be interchangeable. However, manufacturers will usually stock them as replacement parts, and your bike store should be able to determine which one to order. If the manufacturer can't be contacted, there are third party manufacturers and sellers of these hangars.

The picture below, [from Park Tools](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/rear-derailleur-hanger-alignment), shows a bent hangar. Notice how the rear derailleur's cage is at an angle to the cogs. You can usually notice a bent hangar visually. In less obvious cases, bike stores have specialized tools to measure if a hangar is bent and to bend it back.

[image]

Non-replaceable derailleur hangers are part of the dropout, as in the picture below. (Note that this bike is set up and singlespeed, with a derailleur in place you would never put the axle this far forward in the dropout)

[image: derailleur hanger integrated in the frame]

Some steel and titanium bikes have non-replaceable hangars. If these are bent, they will need to be cold set (i.e. bent) back into alignment, although titanium hangars can be difficult to bend. If a non-replaceable derailleur hanger breaks, an experienced welder (preferably a frame builder) will need to replace it.

Comment: why is a separate hanger safer?

Comment: @naught101 because if it bends/breaks you can substitute it. it is actually a breakable part, softer than the frame, so that any force will act on this piece instead of the frame.

Comment: So it's more about safety for the bike than for the rider?

Comment: @naught101 yes. I'm not an english speaker, so feel free to reformulate that part.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the replacement ability not being a primary design point - for off road riding, it seems like this is key, especially on non-steel frames (e.g. aluminum), where the hanger cannot be safely bent back in cases of crashes due to metal fatigue.

Answer (score 17):

### Bearing

A bearing is an interface that enables the axle to rotate inside some fixed part. The axle rolls on the bearings. For example, consider your hubs, pedals, the cranks, and your front fork.
Sheldon Brown has a longer discussion on [bearings](http://sheldonbrown.com/gloss_ba-n.html#bearing). Most bearings are steel balls.

*Preload* is important term related to bearings. For your hubs, preload is how much the hub is getting squeezed in from the side, ignoring the quick release skewer. All cup and cone hubs have inherent preload adjustment, but not all cartridge bearing hubs or other devices do. Too much preload will make the bearings grind and wear out. Too little preload can leave [play](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/58543/) in the hub (i.e. side to side movement when the quick release skewer is clamped) or other device (e.g. crankset, headset will rock back and forth).

Bearings will feel gritty when they are worn or dirty. You can feel this by spinning the wheel in your hand, holding near the axles, or otherwise working the component by hand. In some cases, e.g. you submerged the bike during a river crossing, you can wash out the grease from the bearing, and cause it to sound dry (a whirring sound) but not feel gritty. If the bearing feels notchy or indexed, this can mean too much preload, or that the bearing bore is not round (e.g. it's been ovalized).

### Cup and cone bearings

[image: Wheel bearing -- from Park Tool site]

This type of bearing, pictured above, has the balls rotating between the cup and the cone. The locknut tightens the assembly together, and can be loosened with a standard sized wrench.

Cup and cone bearings require periodic service. Service involves cleaning out the old grease, which may have had some dirt mixed in with it, and adding fresh grease. If the balls are worn, you can measure their size with a caliper and buy replacements. Alternatively, manufacturers' technical documentation will frequently state the size and number of ball bearings; take note that sizes for front and rear hubs may be different. Eventually, the cones should wear, and manufacturers should maintain these as replacement parts as well. The cups may not be replaceable, as they are frequently integrated into the hub or pressed in extremely tightly.

Cup and cone bearings are more traditional and are frequently present on older equipment, but some companies persist in making high-quality cup and cone bearings (notably Shimano and Campagnolo).

Cup and cone hubs all require preload adjustment. Best practice is to tighten the locknuts so that there is barely perceptible play when the hub is off the bike, and zero play when the quick release or thru axle is tightened. Some cartridge bearing hubs require preload adjustment.

### Cartridge bearings

Most manufacturers have moved to cartridge bearings. In many contexts, cartridges are sealed units that can contain things like printer ink, film, or, in bicycles, ball bearings, seals, and races (roughly equivalent to the cone and the cup respectively). Sometimes they are called sealed cartridge bearings, and most of the bearings in bicycles have rubber seals, but this is potentially a misnomer. Bicycle bearings might be unshielded at one end, and cup and cone bearings can have seals built in.

[image]

To replace cartridge bearings, you will need a *bearing extractor* to pull or push the bearing out, and a *bearing press* to push it back in. Related to presses, bearing *drifts* help align the bearings as they are going in. Bike stores frequently have these items. As a makeshift replacement for a bearing press, you can use a block of wood and a hammer, but you need to visually confirm the bearing is going in straight. For bearing extraction, you can use a screwdriver or chisel and a hammer, and carefully hammer the bearing out. Both procedures may damage the bearing seat, however.

The bearings themselves are available commercially from many suppliers. A competent mechanic will know how to measure the bearing size. However, measuring the outer diameter, inner diameter, and depth are often sufficient to give you a bearing size. Bearings are commonly sold by coded numbers, which correspond to size. For example 6806 bearings are common in rear hubs. They have a 42mm outer diameter, 30mm inner diameter, and are 7mm deep.

Bearings are sealed to keep contaminants out. Contaminants would wear the balls or races out. Most bicycle bearings have rubber seals on both sides, but other arrangements exist. If uncertain, check with a mechanic.

Most cartridge bearings are designed not to be serviced. Just replace them when worn. Some higher-end manufacturers (e.g. Chris King, Kogel) design their bearings to be serviced periodically. This entails gently removing the rubber seals, cleaning the grease, and adding fresh grease. If there are no specific instructions, assume that there is no need to service the bearing.

### Durability

Many factors may influence the durability of the bearing. If you ride in wet conditions, this will reduce durability. If you pressure wash your bike, take care not to point the hose straight at the bearings (in your hubs, bottom bracket, rear suspension pivot). As stated earlier, some bearings are more tightly sealed than others, trading off higher friction.

In a press fit bottom bracket, if the bottom bracket seats are not parallel to each other or if one is out of round, that can damage the BB over time. Bearings also have a load capacity. If a piece of equipment was designed with bearings that are too small to take the loads applied to it, that would also impact bearing life. Additionally, all else equal, the more narrowly spaced the bearings are, the higher the loads on them will be. This does affect some press fit standards, like BB30 and PF30, which have their bearings more narrowly spaced than others. Last, the material quality of bearings and the races they run on has an impact. This would include the specific steel alloys used as well as their pureness, and how smooth they are.

#### Miscellaneous

Ceramic bearings are sometimes offered as an upgrade on high-end bikes. They have marginally lower rolling resistance than high-quality steel ball bearings. In many industrial applications, ceramic bearings are thought to be more durable, but this may or may not transfer to bicycling applications. In addition, ceramic bearings are extremely hard, and they must be paired with a high-quality steel race, or else they can dent the race when the bike goes over bumps. Many cheap ceramic bearings may skimp on the quality of the races, and buyers should beware.

[Bushings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_bearing#Bushing) (link to Wikipedia) are another form of bearing. These involve a sleeve rotating over the axle. Bushings are often used in rear derailer jockey wheels and in mountain bike [suspension](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/64405/38270).

Comment: Anyone who has the knowledge, please feel free to expand on this.

Answer (score 16):

### Headset

The group of bearings and bearing cups that allows the steer tube to turn freely within the head tube. Headsets come in two basic varieties.

**Threaded headsets** are common on older bikes and inexpensive bikes. They are called "threaded" headsets because the top race is held on with a threaded race and locknut which thread onto a threaded portion of the steerer tube.

[image: Threaded Headset]

**Threadless headsets** are standard on modern mid-level and high-end bicycles. They are called "threadless" headsets because there are no threads on the race or steerer tube nor is there a lock ring. The headset is held together by pressure created by a bolt through the top cap which threads into a star nut inside the steerer tube.

[image: Threadless Headset]

Images courtesy of [Sheldon Brown](http://sheldonbrown.com/gloss_ha-i.html).

Answer (score 15):

### Gear Inches

One of the several ways to describe gearing; how hard/easy the bike is to pedal. The actual figure is the equivalent diameter of the wheel if you were on a direct pedal cycle like a unicycle or an old fashioned high-wheeler. It does allow for different size wheels as well as the gears, but it ignores the effect of different crank lengths.

Easier to pedal (granny-gears) have low gear inches (smaller equivalent wheel).  Harder to pedal gears have higher gear inches.

The basic formula is:

```
GI = (CrT/CogT)*D
WHERE
GI     = Gear Inches
CrT    = Chain Ring Teeth
CogT   = Cog Teeth
D      = Wheel and Tire Diameter
```

For example, a 700c tire is going to have a diameter of roughly 26.3" (depending on the width of the tire). Note that larger tires on the same wheel will give higher gearing (i.e. more gear inches), even though the *gearing* (i.e. chainring and cog) are the same. If you have shifted to your smallest front ring of 24 teeth, and your biggest rear cog of 27 teeth then your gear inches are:

```
GI = (24/27)*26.3 = 23.4"
```

Note: if you want to take the math a little further - and of course I do since I am a [math nut](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1549/i-wish-to-get-fit-therefore-should-i-have-a-heavy-bike/1558#1558) - you can find how far you travel each pedal stroke by remembering that:

```
Circumference = pi*Diameter
```

In our example:

```
Circumference = 3.14*23.4" = 73.5
```

**Note:** you can search for Bicycle Gear Calculator and find several pages online that will do the math for you.  There will be a lot of variation and calculators use different rounding and make different assumptions about wheel width. Pre-prepared tables are available, calculated for ETRTO 23-622 (700c x 23mm) tyres or in the case of traditional track racers' tables, a "standard" wheel with an assumed 27" overall diameter.

Answer (score 15):

### Chain Tug

AKA: Chain Tensioner

On most bikes, the rear derailleur keeps the chain in tension. On [fixed gear](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/271#271), single speed, or hub geared bikes, a chain tensioner is required to keep the chain in tension. Without this mechanism, the chain may fall off, or the rear wheel may pull forward while pedaling.

[image: Chain tug 1] [image: Chain tug 2]

Some chain tugs are available with [derailleur hangers](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/3665#3665) to allow horizontal droput bikes to run derailleur gearing systems.

[image]

More information about chain tugs is available in [this answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4341/chain-loses-tension-on-straight-drop-out/4347#4347).

**Bottom Bracket mounted Chain Tensioners**:
Typically seen on downhill styled mountain bikes.

[image: Bottom Bracket Chain Tensioner]
[image: Bottom Bracket Chain Tensioner on bicycle]

Comment: Small correction: A chain tug is only used and required with those horizontal, rear-facing drop outs. And that is not popular everywhere. In other countries, single speed  and IGH bikes use forward facing dropouts where the axle is held in place by friction (requires proper tightening of the axle nuts). This makes it extremely easy to take out the rear wheel, or to replace it (no need to open the chain lock, you can simply pick the chain off the sprocket *after* taking out the wheel), and is surprisingly robust if tightened properly.

Answer (score 13):

### Bottom Bracket (BB)

The [cranks](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/3157#3157) attach to the bottom bracket (BB), which contains [bearings](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/2758#2758) that let the axle rotate. BBs may incorporate the axle the axle that the cranks attach to, or the axle may be bonded to the cranks and pass through the BB. The bottom bracket *shell* is the part of the frame holding the bottom bracket. Road and mountain bikes have different BB shell widths, so you can't interchange their cranksets.

**Threaded bottom brackets**

Traditional bottom brackets screw into the bottom bracket shell. Many frames with threaded BBs use a standard called the Birmingham Small Arms (BSA) standard, also called English, British, or ISO. Italian bikes are more likely to use Italian threading. There are a few older standards, which [Sheldon Brown describes](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/cribsheet-bottombrackets.html). To replace a threaded bottom bracket, you will need to know your frame’s shell type.

For a time, Shimano and others built on this style of BB with oversized hollow spindles. These were stiffer and lighter, but the spindle left less room for bearings and the BBs may have been less durable as a result.

External bottom bracket cups came into play in the mid 2000s. Here, the bottom bracket assembly contains only the bearings, and the crank axle is attached to one or both crankarms. The axle goes through the bottom bracket.

**Press-fit bottom brackets**

Later, various press-fit bottom bracket standards were developed for carbon fiber bikes. It is not possible to cut threads into carbon fiber, and press fit systems are a bit lighter. The alternative was to bond an aluminum threaded sleeve in. However, press fit has a reputation for creaking, in part due to inability to maintain tight [tolerances](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/81703/38270) during carbon manufacture.

There are numerous press fit standards. Cups for one standard are not interchangeable with a different standard. However, for each press fit BB standard, manufacturers will make cups to accept most or all cranksets on the market. Examples of open standards include BB86 and Press Fit 30. Some larger bike manufacturers have BB standards proprietary to their own frames, such as Cervelo (BBRight), Cannondale (BB30 and descendants), and Trek (BB90, although they appear to be transitioning to the open, threaded T47 standard as of 2021).

## Maintenance

Most BBs use cartridge bearings. The whole BB is replaced when the bearings are worn, as discussed in the [article on bearings](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/2758#2758). Some BBs with cartridge bearings may be serviceable, which usually involves removing the seals, using a degreaser or WD40 to clean the bearings, and then regreasing, but most of the time the bearings themselves aren't physically accessible. Riders should avoid spraying water directly at the BB from the side of the bike when cleaning it.

### Selecting a Bottom Bracket

For square taper systems, you need to know the length of the taper (e.g. 108mm) and the type (JIS or ISO). A bike store can help you measure the length if you don’t know it. For modern cranks, you need to know both the BB shell type (e.g. BSA, PF30) and axle type (e.g. Shimano, SRAM DUB, Campagnolo, other). For example, a BB described as PF30-24 or similar wording fits a PF30 shell, and it can only take a 24mm spindle (i.e. Shimano, although some third-party cranks make compatible spindles). PF30-DUB would fit a PF30 shell with a SRAM DUB (28.99mm) axle. Confusingly, if a BB were to be described just as PF30 with no other suffix, you can assume it fits a PF30 shell and a 30mm axle.

Most but not all crank spindles can mount to most BB shell types. Manufacturers even make BBs for 30mm spindles in BSA and Italian shells, even though a 30mm spindle is a tight fit in those shells. One clear exception is that Trek's proprietary BB90 standard is incompatible with many 30mm spindles. There may be a few more cases of incompatible hardware.

Last, if you have a BBs designed for larger spindles and you wish to fit a crank with a smaller spindle, this *may* be possible through adapters. For example, 30mm to 24mm spindle adaptors exist, and SRAM's older GXP spindle (22mm on the non-drive side, 24mm elsewhere) fits in a Shimano-compatible BB with one adapter. In general, arrangements with adapters are more likely to creak than using the correct equipment. This is because the combined system has [greater variances in dimension](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/81703/38270). Also, not all systems can be adapted.

Also note that there are eccentric bottom brackets, which are really a bottom bracket that goes inside of an offset bottom bracket shell that fits inside the frame's bottom bracket shell. This allows the bottom bracket to be moved a bit, to tension the chain on a single-speed or fixed-gear bike.

- Sheldon Brown on [bottom brackets](http://sheldonbrown.com/gloss_bo-z.html#bottom)

#### Miscellaneous terms and concepts

- The right (drive-side) cup on BSA BBs is *left*-hand threaded, i.e. you tighten it *counter*-clockwise. This may be counterintuitive, but if the thread directions were reversed, [pedaling would tend to unscrew](https://www.velonews.com/gear/technical-faq-are-bottom-bracket-threads-backward/) the cups. Italian BBs are right-hand threaded on both sides, and their drive-side cup sometimes comes out unless fixed with adhesive, e.g. Loctite.
- If a BB shell's threads are damaged, e.g. by cross-threading (screwing something in at an angle), they can be *chased* by a tap to restore them. This can also be called *reaming*.
- Metal bottom bracket shells should ideally be *faced* before frame assembly. Facing means making sure the lips of the BB shell are exactly parallel to each other, shaving down any excess metal or carbon. In the photograph below, the BB shell has *not* been faced properly. The cup is at a slight angle, as you can see by the small gap towards the top of the photo. This can lead to creaking or to shortened bearing life. Press fit shells and disc brake mounts, including on carbon bikes, can also benefit from facing.

[image]

Comment: Note: may be at the front or back of the bike rather than the bottom. And is not a bracket.

Comment: I've recently been made aware of sealed, unsealed, and external BBs. Can here anyone expand on the difference between them?

Comment: This actually describes the bottom bracket shell. The bottom bracket is the bearing assembly and is usually removable...

Comment: @freiheit - fixed, feel free to edit further.

Comment: Ok, I edited the heck out of it. I didn't mention sealed/unsealed, but I did explain external BBs and tried to explain the new external-style-but-actually-go-inside-a-larger-shell-BB style that I can't figure out the standard name for (it's called "press-fit" on one of my bikes, but the same thing also can screw in...)

Comment: @GoodbyeStackExchange i wonder if this referred to cartridge BBs, as distinct from cartridge bearings. This meant that the Bb itself was a sealed unit containing bearings and the spindle. I think that term is no longer common, but I could be wrong and I welcome discussion.

Answer (score 13):

### Chain gauge

Measures the stretch of a chain to determine how worn it is and when to replace it.
It's made to fit exactly between two separated links of a standard chain.
Synonyms include: chain wear gauge, chain checker
[image: chain guage]

Alternately you can measure the chain with a ruler - standard links are 1inch (25.4mm) long.

Note - the chain doesn't actually stretch, the pins connecting the links wear away making the joints looser. The extra movement reduces efficiency, causes the chain to skip and will wear the rear gear teeth.

Comment: Note that tools that work this way are [not especially accurate](http://pardo.net/bike/pic/fail-004/000.html), to work properly both measurement points should be on the same side of the pin they're measuring.

Answer (score 13):

### Fender (US usage)

### Mudguard (UK usage)

### Mudflaps

A must for winter or wet weather cycling. As the wheel rotates, it will spray water and dirt up a rider's back, onto various parts of the frame and drivetrain, and onto riders behind. Fenders block this spray. They are often recommended for riding in wet weather. They may even be required on some group rides, depending on climate.

Mudguards are flaps attached at the ends of a fender that reduce spray further. They are usually bought separately from the fender.

[image: fender / mudguard]

Commercial fenders can be made from metal or plastic. Fenders and/or mudguards can also be DIY'ed from plastic milk cartons. Full coverage fenders require the frame and fork to have fender mounts. However, some fenders, like the ones depicted, can attach on to the frame and fork directly. This mounting is less secure, and such fenders do not cover as much of the wheel.

If an object like a stick gets jammed between the tire and fender, it can cause the fender to break off. The frame may be damaged as well. If there is not much clearance between the fender and tire, this may be an argument for using fenders made for race bikes. These fenders may just bolt to the seat stay and down tube, and will offer partial protection from dirt and water.

Related: the fender [stays](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/81592/38270) are the rods that connect to dedicate mounts on the bike.

Comment: A link to a good DIY fender tutorial would be good here.

Comment: I'd suggest that a mudflap is different to a mudguard or fender. Mudflap is usually the wide, flexible extension which hangs on the rear end of the mudguard: https://www.sjscycles.co.uk/mudguards-mudflaps/

Comment: It should be added that some road-riding clubs see mudguards as mandatory for wet and/or winter rides - the reason being that they stop the rider behind you getting a mouth full of whatever is currently on the road.

Answer (score 13):

## **Groupset**

A groupset or *gruppo* (from the Italian for "group") refers to the components involved in shifting gears, braking, and transmitting power from the rider's legs to the rear wheel. Relatedly, sometimes people say "drivetrain." In bicycles, the term is not formally defined, but it definitely includes the chain, chainrings, and cassette.

Groupsets typically include:

- integrated brake levers/shifters (on older bikes, brake levers and down-tube or bar-end shifters)
- front and rear brakes (including calipers/pads or rotors/disks/pads)
- rear derailleur
- front derailleur (unless the bike has a 1x drivetrain)
- bottom bracket
- crankset or chainset
- chain
- [cassette](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/82208#82208) (freewheel on older bikes)
- cables and housings or hydraulic hoses as appropriate (for electronic groupsets, control wires and batteries)

In the past, groupsets have included some or all of the following components or groupset manufacturers have offered these items, but these are not considered parts of the groupset.

- headset
- hubs and usually quick release skewers
- stem and seatpost may have been included, or may have been optional purchases
- pedals are typically optional purchases

[image: SRAM Red Groupset]

Shimano, SRAM, and Campagnolo account for the vast majority of road bike groupsets. [SRAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRAM_Corporation) had entered the road bike market in 1988, then exited, then re-entered in 2004. Shimano and SRAM are the majority of the mountain bike groupset market. [Campagnolo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campagnolo) briefly produced one mountain bike groupset before exiting that market. At the time of writing, Full Speed Ahead and Rotor have produced groupsets as well, but these have yet to achieve widespread take up.

Groupsets are offered at a range of price points. Each of the 3 major manufacturers makes one version for professional road (e.g. Campagnolo Super Record) or mountain bike racing (e.g. SRAM XX1). They also offer various lower level groupsets for consumers. Generally, the high-performance consumer groupsets (e.g. Shimano 105 and Ultegra) will have less exotic material (i.e. less titanium and carbon fiber) used in manufacture and will be heavier, but will usually offer very similar performance on other characteristics (e.g. durability, shift quality). Groupset manufacturers generally offer electronic shifting versions of their top two groupsets.

The original equipment manufacturer (OEM) market is dominated by Shimano and SRAM (i.e. most complete bicycles come with Shimano or SRAM components). For the most part, shifters and derailleurs are not compatible between brands, and complete bicycles will not mix these components. However, some complete bicycles will substitute cranksets and/or brakes from third party manufacturers for cost or performance reasons.

Comment: Is "drivetrain" a synonym of "groupset?" I've heard the two words used almost interchangeably in many contexts.

Comment: @Jules In motorized vehicles, drivetrain is the set of components that deliver power from the engine to the wheels (excludes the motor). On bikes, I believe that people usually mean the crank, chain, and rear derailleur. It may include the cassette. In principle, the pedals connect the cranks to your legs, so maybe they should be included. I don't think this would fit with common usage (but I could be wrong).

Answer (score 12):

### Handlebars

The part of the bike you hold with your hands. When you turn the handlebars, the front wheel turns with them. The [stem](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/270#270) clamps onto the handlebar and onto your fork steerer.

Broadly speaking, there are flat handlebars as found on mountain bikes and hybrid bikes, and drop handlebars which have bar ends that are curved below the flat portion. Flat handlebars offer better control in rough terrain. Drop handlebars are used on road and gravel bikes, and they offer a wide variety of hand positions. [This question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/5251/how-to-use-drop-handlebars-properly) discusses in some detail the various positions you can take on drop bars.

If you are replacing handlebars, they are mainly characterized by their width. For drop bars, one guideline for road bikes is that the bars should approximately equal your shoulder width. Gravel cyclists frequently opt for relatively wide bars, and they also opt for flared bars where the drops are wider than the hoods. Professional road racers are increasingly opting for narrow bars. Mountain bike handlebars are significantly wider than road bars, and are frequently trimmed to the desired length after some experimentation.

[This question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1195/different-kinds-of-handlebars/1208) discusses different subtypes of each of the two classes of handlebars.

#### Additional information:

Sheldon Brown on [handlebars](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/gloss_ha-i.html#handlebar), [drop bars](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/gloss_dr-z.html#dropbar), and [upright bars](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/gloss_u-v.html#upright).

Answer (score 12):

### Cable Stretcher

#### A.K.A. "Fourth Hand" brake tool

[image: a]

The cable stretcher is used to stretch brake cables when installing brakes or new cable. It can also be used to tighten zip ties.

Comment: Can you explain what you would use it for? I'm betting most people don't install their own brake cables.

Comment: I have never had problems installing brake cables with a standard set of pliers.

Comment: @Ian - I've frayed cables by doing this. Perhaps I need practice!

Comment: @neilfein, I tend to solder the ends of cables after I have cut them to stop any fraying.

Comment: you could also use the wire-end crimp/slip covers used in electronic devices to cover them.

Comment: Wow, I usually just install my brake cables by hand. It's really easy with most systems, especially side pulls, where you can arbitrarily tension the cables without using any force before tightening the nut.

Comment: @Ian superglue also works!

Comment: I'd know this as a third-hand tool.   I have two hands, if this tool is the fourth hand.... who or what is the third hand ?   the pinch bolt you're tightening ?   LATER UPDATE - the "third hand" tool is one that holds the rim brake pads against the rim so you have your first two hands to manage the pinch bolt and tool.

Answer (score 12):

### Track pump or floor pump

A large pump that you use by standing on the bottom plate and moving the handle up and down. Despite the name, these are not limited to track bikes. You can use both hands and your back to pump a high pressure tire quickly and easily. Generally for use at home - or at the track - rather than for carrying on the bike. Some manufacturers make portable track pumps which bolt to the down tube for easier inflation of high pressure tires.

[image: track pump]

Features to look for:

- sturdy construction
- pressure gauge
- a head that can be used with both [Presta](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/283#283) and [Schrader](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/284#284) valves
- Optional: a secondary air chamber to seat tubeless tires

Manufacturers may sell spare parts for pumps that break. If your pump is leaking air or not inflating, it’s possible that you may just need to change a rubber o-ring inside the pump. Replacement gauges are another common item.

Comment: Also useful for Dunlop valves (which are very much still used by bicycle users in some countries.)

Answer (score 12):

## Hub

One of the central parts of a conventional bicycle wheel. Hubs are flanged metal tubes, somewhat similar in shape to spools of thread. Hubs contains [bearings](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/2758#2758) and an axle, and they are connected to the rims via spokes. The rear hub holds the freewheel or cassette.

### Maintenance

The bearings in your hubs are wear items. This is discussed more in the bearing article, but cup and cone hubs require annual service. The cones may eventually wear out and can be replaced. Cartridge bearings usually do not require service, but they will eventually wear out. A competent bike store or a consumer with the right tools can pull them and replace them. The freehub body can often be obtained from the hub manufacturer as a replacement if it wears out. If the hub is OEM equipment on a complete bicycle, the bike store should be able to search for replacements in their inventory.

Good hubs can outlast a rim. Currently, many consumers buy complete wheels, but you can also buy separate hubs and ask someone to build you a wheel, or have a hub from a damaged wheel taken out and reused. If you damage or wear out a rim, consider if rebuilding on the same hub is more cost-effective than buying a whole new wheel.

### For consumers, some key features are:

1. **Spacing and axle type**

If you are getting a new wheel, you will need to make sure that these features match your current bike. Quick release road and MTB hubs had 130 and 135mm over-locknut diameter respectively. On thru axle hubs, road hubs wheels use a consistent spacing and mostly use 12mm diameter [thru axles](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/41723/) front and rear. MTB hubs likely use 15mm diameter thru axles, but you need to consider if the bike uses Boost spacing (148mm in the rear) or not (142mm, same as disc road bikes).

2. **Drivetrain**

You need to match the rear hub's freehub body to your drivetrain. Shimano road hubs have mainly used the Hyperglide system, but the 12s Dura Ace hubs are transitioning to a different spline system (name not yet determined), and they use the Microspline system for MTBs. SRAM has shifted to the XD and XDR driver systems. Campagnolo has maintained its own freehub spline pattern, with an additional variant (called N3W) to accommodate the small cogs on its Ekar gravel groupset. Alternatively, you may have a freewheel hub, and you would thread a freewheel onto the hub.

If you switch drivetrains, replacement freehub bodies are usually available from the hub manufacturer.

3. **Disc or rim brake**

Hubs designed for disc brakes will have their flanges spaced so as to accommodate the rotor, and they will have a mounting system. As to the latter, the two rotor mount standards are 6-bolt (mostly used on MTBs) and centerlock (used on drop bar bikes). Rim brake hubs cannot be used in disc brake systems, as there is nowhere to mount the rotor.

4. **Other features**

- [Internally geared](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/1728#1728) hubs contain all the gears inside the hub. They don't have freewheels, but they do have an external cog to attach a chain or belt drive. These typically have higher drivetrain friction than (properly maintained) derailleur-based systems, but they are much more resistant to contamination. They may use belt drives or chains for the transmission.
- [Track/fixed-gear](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/271#271) hubs may have narrower spacing than other hubs. They will not have a cassette body, and they will accept a thread-on cog on one side of the hub.
- [Flip-flop](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/1982#1982) hubs have a cog is mounted on either side of the wheel. According to legend, Tullio Campagnolo was inspired to develop the quick release skewer when he tried to flip a flip-flop hub secured by wingnuts in cold weather. This may not be strictly true, but Campagnolo was one of the first to put a high-quality quick release skewer into serial production.
- Both front and rear hubs can accommodate electric motors. Users should be aware that they will change the bike's weight distribution and thus its handling. The batteries are mounted elsewhere on the bike. The crankset is an alternative area for mounting a motor (i.e. a mid drive e-bike).

Comment: What is the actual name of the cylinder on which cassette goes? Wikipedia states "splined shaft", here you use term just "splines".

Answer (score 12):

### Chainstay Length

The chainstay length is measured from the center of the front chainring (centered on the bottom bracket spindle) to the center of the rear cog (centered on the rear axle). Longer chainstays stabilize the bike's handling. Touring and many gravel bikes have longer chainstays, whereas many racing bikes, especially on the track, have short ones.

The chainstay length is typically measured directly from point to point but might be measured horizontally (parallel to the ground) which will give a slightly [shorter value](https://images.app.goo.gl/yA1wkEz7rviLEg8V7). If possible, check the geometry chart to see how it is defined. Frames with horizontal or adjustable [dropouts](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/23046/8273) have variable chainstay length, unlike frames with vertical dropouts. In the former case, the manufacturer may state the chainstay length as measured to the middle of the adjustment range.

[image: Chainstay Length]

There are formulae for calculating chain length, based on chainstay length and cog sizes, which are used in online [chain length calculator](http://www.machinehead-software.co.uk/bike/chain_length/chainlengthcalc.html).

Answer (score 11):

### Rack, aka Luggage Carrier

A rack is a frame attached to a bicycle to provide space for a pannier or other type of pack to be attached. Not all frames and forks are built with rack mounts. Racks can be mounted at the rear of a bicycle, for example on the touring bike below:
[image]

Or front racks mount to the fork, as shown in a photo from [Cyclingabout.com](https://www.cyclingabout.com/all-about-front-racks-bicycle-touring/):

[image]

#### Reference:

- [Sheldon Brown's Bicycle Glossary: Rack](http://sheldonbrown.com/gloss_ra-e.html#rack)

Answer (score 11):

### Saddle

Also called the seat, the saddle is where the rider sits.

- Sheldon Brown on [saddles](http://sheldonbrown.com/gloss_sa-o.html#saddle).

[image]

Gel saddle

[image]

Leather saddle

[image]

Plastic saddle

Answer (score 11):

### Disc Hub

Disc hubs are designed to mount disc rotors. Rotor mounts come in two varieties: 6-bolt ISO and Shimano's proprietary Centerlock spline. Converters exist to allow a Centerlock hub to accept a six-bolt disc rotor.

**6-bolt ISO:**

[image: ISO disc hub]

**Shimano Centerlock:**
(Note, centerlock hubs ship with a rubber cover over the centerlock splines).
[image: Centerlock disc hub]

You cannot mount a disc rotor on a non-disc hub. You can use a 6-bolt rotor with a groupset that is otherwise designed for centerlock rotors or vice versa.

Comment: Most Rohloff hubs are also "disk hubs", and come with a proprietary 4 hole mount. No adapter is possible, the reason they do this is because they need a bigger hole than the other mounts allow.

Answer (score 11):

### Hub Skewer

A metal rod with a clamping mechanism that attaches the [hub](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/3404#3404)/wheel assembly to the fork or frame. Many skewers are equipped with a [quick-release mechanism](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/404#404) that allow removing the wheel without tools, facilitating changing a tire, putting a bike in the back seat of a car, etc. Unfortunately, the trade-off for easy wheel removal is that it's easier for thieves to remove a quick-release wheel. Skewers without a quick release will use a hex or Torx wrench for removal. It is also possible to secure the wheels with [axle nuts](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/42804#42804), many of which use a crescent wrench of appropriate size.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

### Frame or frameset

The frame is the skeleton of a bicycle. It's the part that all other parts are attached to. (Some parts, like the front wheel, are attached to other parts that are in turn attached to the frame.) A frame plus a fork are often called a frameset. The frameset's geometry determines the bike's handling characteristics.

Frames are usually made of steel, aluminum, carbon fiber, or titanium. Less common frame materials include bamboo, other types of wood, or magnesium alloy.

Aluminum mountain bicycle frame:

[image: 100_7864]

Parts of a bicycle frame:

[image]

(Image from wikipedia; [credit and legalese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Bicycle_Frame_Diagram-en.svg))

Answer (score 11):

### Brifter

A combined brake and shift lever. May be called integrated shifters. On road bikes, “shifter” may be understood to include the brake lever as well, but this is *not* true for mountain bikes. The specific term may be more common in the UK than the US. The image below shows a Campagnolo brifter for road bikes.

[image: brifter]

Reference:

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shifter_%28bicycle_part%29#Combined_brake_and_shift_levers)

Answer (score 11):

### Tyre Saver

Small loop of wire attached so that it rubs continuously on the tyre as it rotates. This brushes off debris and reduces the number of punctures. These were popular mainly in the 1970's and 1980's, with the advent of lightweight puncture-resistant tyres they have almost disappeared.

[image: tyre saver]

Comment: Good work Mσᶎ. I think we also called them stone pickers or tire pickers, but my recent research only found stone picking machines to remove stones from farmland.

Answer (score 10):

### Folding Bike

#### AKA Folder

A bike that's designed to fold down to a small package without disassembly. They usually have smaller wheels, and are designed to be taken on trains and buses. Many transit organizations that don't allow bikes during peak hours will allow folding bikes during these busy times. They also reduce storage space requirements, often useful in city apartments.

There are also bikes that do not fold, but are designed to be taken apart easily, with frame latches, [quick-release](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/404#404) latches, or hybrid folding/unlatching systems.

[image: Folding bike, ready to ride]

[Folding bike, ready to ride](http://www.flickr.com/photos/neilfein/4446499840/in/set-72157623528349037/)

[image: Folding bike, in folded position]

[Folding bike, in folded position](http://www.flickr.com/photos/neilfein/2629625311/)

Answer (score 10):

### Internally-Geared Hub

A setup where the gearing mechanism is sealed in the rear wheel's hub, away from water, road salt, and other contaminants. Internally-geared hubs require much less in the way of cleaning than traditional drive-trains. These hubs are popular with commuters or other utility cyclists who frequently ride in snow and rain. They are also popular on [folding bikes](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/263#263), as they are suited for bikes taken on crowded trains. When coupled with a single front chainring, IGH drivetrains permit the installation of a full chain guard, which most external gear systems don't allow. They can also shift when the bicycle is completely stopped, unlike derailleur drivetrains. Gearboxes are related, and they put the gears in the bottom bracket area.

Internal hubs are slightly heavier than comparable external drive-trains. They also have [greater drivetrain friction](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/188/whats-the-efficiency-of-hub-gears-compared-to-derailleurs) than a well-maintained external drivetrain.

They will typically require oil to lubricate the gears, which can be injected through a port.

[image: Hub]

Reference:

- [Sheldon Brown: Internal-Gear Hubs](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/internal-gears.html)

Answer (score 10):

### Master link

#### Also known as:

- **Quick link**
- **Breakable link**
- **PowerLink**™ (made by SRAM)
- **MissingLink** (made by KMC)

A link inserted onto a chain so that the chain can be both assembled and "broken" (disassembled) without a [chain tool](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/3480#3480). A set of pliers or a flathead screwdriver is usually sufficient to disassemble a chain with a master link.

Master link pliers are available to open a master link. Note that not all designs of master link are sold as suitable for re-use.

More information at [Sheldon Brown's site](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/gloss_m.html#masterlink).

[image]

[Image from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_link)

Answer (score 9):

### Saddlebag

(a.k.a. seat bag, wedge bag, etc.) Small bag designed to be attached to the underside of a bicycle saddle, usually large enough to hold tools to change a flat tire.

The name "saddlebag" is often mistakenly applied to [panniers](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/402#402) which resemble saddlebags used on motorcycles or horse saddles.

Comment: also known as a wedge-bag/pack

Answer (score 9):

### Rim

The circular, U-shaped (in cross-section) part of a bicycle wheel that the tire and spokes are attached to. Rims attach to the hubs with spokes. *Wheel-building* is the process of attaching a hub to a rim with spokes, including bringing the spokes up to tension.

With rim brakes, the rim's braking surface will eventually wear out. The metal will become dangerously thin, and it may crack, as this image from Sheldon Brown's site shows. Some rims have a dimple in the sidewall as a wear indicator. When the wear indicator is no longer visible, replace the rim. Otherwise, check for concavity by holding a ruler to the rim. The photograph below was originally posted to the [Bike Radar forum](https://forum.bikeradar.com/discussion/13079601/rim-wear-how-worn-is-worn-out-pics-included) and it depicts a rim due for replacement. Wear due to braking is not an issue with disc brakes, as that is borne by the disc rotors.

[image]

This image shows a worn rim that has cracked.

[image]

#### Maintenance

- If you ride in the wet with rim brakes, it is good to clean off your rims and brake pads afterward, as the grit from the road will abrade your rims.
- Rims can come *out of true*, i.e. they will wobble side to side or up and down (the latter is sometimes called being out of round). They can be trued by adjusting the spoke nipples. Tightening a nipple increases the spoke's tension, which pulls the affected rim segment in the direction of the spoke. Wheels, especially mass produced ones, do not always come true from the factory. Most cyclists get a bike store to do this, but you can true your wheels at home with a *spoke wrench* and, preferably, a *truing stand*. You can use the frame and/or your brake pads as a makeshift stand, but commercial ones are available.
- If an aluminum rim gets bent in a crash, it can often be straightened. This is less necessary on disc brake wheels that are not being set up tubeless.
- If you must replace a rim due to a crash, consider if reusing the hub is more economical than buying a new wheel. If the damaged wheel does not use proprietary spokes or rim drilling patterns, you are not limited to replacement rims from the original manufacturer. Make sure to match the number of holes in the old rim to the new one. Old spokes are generally not reused, and a different rim will require different length spokes anyway. A bike store can help you determine the spoke lengths that are needed. Some examples of major rim manufacturers with a wide range of price points are DT Swiss, Velocity, and Kinlin, although there are numerous others.

#### Characteristics

Buyers comparing rims or complete wheels (often called wheelsets) may be interested in the following characteristics.

- Size: Rims are often given a nominal size. The formal way to measure size is the [diameter at the bead seats](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/67892/38558), in millimeters. 700c road bike wheels and 29" MTB wheels share the same BSD of 622mm. These are the most common wheel sizes in these disciplines. The Bead Seat Diameter article, linked earlier, has more discussion.
- Internal width: this is the width measured between the bead hooks if present, or the inner faces of the sidewall if the rim is hookless. All else equal, the same tire will be wider on a rim with wider internal width. Internal widths have grown much wider over time for both road and mountain bikes. *External* width is sometimes listed, but it is arguably less important unless you’re trying to maximize aerodynamics (here, you ideally want your tires to measure narrower than the external width).
- Tire types and hooked or hookless: Tubeless-compatible rims can fit tubed or tubeless clincher tires. You can run a tubeless clincher with a tube inside. Older clincher rims may *not* accept tubeless tires, so check that a rim explicitly indicates tubeless compatibility if this is important. More rarely, rims can fit tubular tires, which are glued to the rim bed. At the time of writing, many MTB wheels and newer road wheels, especially carbon ones, are *hookless*, meaning that they don’t have bead hooks. Not all clincher tires are compatible with hookless rims, so make sure your tire explicitly states this. Hookless rims are easier and cheaper to construct in carbon. Tubular tires **do not fit** on clincher rims, and vice versa. Tubulars are extensively used in professional road racing, and they are typically safer to run if punctured than clinchers, but you have to be able to prepare and glue the tires (or pay someone to do so).
- Holes: Relevant if replacing a rim or having a wheel built. Fewer spokes means slightly more aerodynamic wheels, although the differences are small. Rims and wheels for performance road bikes may be available in 20, 24, 28, or 32 spokes, with 20 spokes typically only being available for front rim brake wheels. Rims for tandem road bikes tend to have more spokes.
- Tire widths: You can mostly mount whatever width of tire you want on the rim. [This discussion](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/what-is-the-maximum-tire-or-minimum-tire-width-i-can-fit-on-my-bicycle/69522#69522) has more information on what width of tires are compatible with rims. However, the [frame's tire clearance](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/44014/38270) is more likely to be the limiting factor than the rim. Some aerodynamic wheels will specify what tire widths are optimal to maximize aerodynamics. Some rims may explicitly state a minimum width. Check the manufacturer website for details.
- Aluminum rims are extruded as a bar, then rolled into a rim. The ends of the bar are [pinned together, held together by a sleeve, or welded](https://astralcycling.com/pages/faqs#t4). Pinned rims are generally the cheapest. Carbon rims are made in one piece in a mold. They can be made lighter than aluminum rims of the same depth. A deep, aerodynamic aluminum rim would be very heavy. Carbon rims for rim brakes generally have poorer braking than aluminum rims, although rims and brake pads have improved.

Clincher rims require [tape](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/59097/24228) on the rim bed to cover the holes that are used to insert spoke nipples. A few clincher rims may not have these holes, and the manufacturer will explicitly say if this is the case.

Answer (score 9):

### Crank, aka chainset, crankset

We turn the pedals and cranks with our legs. Pedals screw into threads at the end of the crankarms. The cranks themselves are, in turn, attached to the [bottom bracket](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/2759#2759). Gearing is controlled by the size of the front chainring(s).

Some key concepts:

- Length: Cranks have traditionally been available in lengths of 170mm, 172.5mm, and 175mm, with many manufacturers now offering shorter or occasionally longer lengths too. Mountain bikers riding long-travel bikes and triathlon cyclists may have started this trend of using shorter cranks.
- Chainrings: Cranks are usually designed for use with between 1 to 3 chainrings, although 4-ring designs have existed historically. The chainrings control the gearing available to the bicycle. 1x systems with a single front chainring (pronounced "one-by") are common on mountain bikes and gravel bikes. They frequently have teeth specially designed to retain the chain (e.g. narrow-wide chainring). Other technologies such as a clutched rear derailleur and possibly a chain guide aid chain retention also. 2x systems are common on road bikes, and have pins and ramps to guide the chain to the large ring. Triple chainrings were once standard on MTBs. They may be more common on older touring bikes also. Front derailleurs are typically specific to triple or double chainrings.
- [Bolt circle diameter](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/55802/32314): determines what sizes of chainring can attach to the crankset. Some cranksets use direct mount chainrings instead, which are secured to a splined interface at the crank arm. Different manufacturers have different spline patterns, and bolt patterns may vary too despite the BCD value.
- [Bottom bracket](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/2759#2759) attachment or axle type: Cranksets may be designed to mate to a specific bottom bracket, in the case of square tapered, older Shimano Hollowtech, or ISIS cranksets. Alternatively, cranksets may be designed around a specific axle type. For example, Shimano, SRAM, and Campagnolo use 22.00 to 28.99mm diameter axles. Some third party cranksets have 30mm axles. Bottom brackets are not necessarily inter-compatible despite being designed for the same spindle diameter, so be sure to check with manufacturer guidelines. Note: some “24mm” FSA cranks are actually 24.07mm and will not readily fit standard 24.00mm bottom brackets.
- Chainline: the distance from the centre of the bottom bracket to the center of the chainrings or chainring. Typically, road double cranksets have a 43.5mm chainline. Non-boost MTB cranksets are around 50mm, but wider chain lines are available for boost and super boost bikes. The advent of disc brakes on road and gravel bikes has led to some cranksets with 45mm chainlines. Front derailleurs are designed for optimal performance on a specific chain line. Mixing a road front derailleur with a 45mm chainline crankset may work, but it may not be optimal. Mixing a road derailleur with a 50mm chainline is very unlikely to work.
- Maintenance: The cranks themselves don’t typically require maintenance, but the chainrings will wear eventually. Typically, they will outlast the cassette.

#### Miscellaneous:

- Cranksets can also connect to motors attached around the bottom bracket (on E-bikes) and/or to gearboxes mounted in the bottom bracket area.
- Sheldon Brown has more information on [cranks](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/gloss_cn-z.html#crank).

[[image: Crank arms]](https://flic.kr/p/nyQzv4)

Answer (score 9):

## Spider (part of the crankset)

The part that connects the [crank](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/3157#3157) arms to the chain rings. You bolt the chainrings to the spider. In the past, you merely needed to find chainrings appropriate to your transmission (e.g. 8 speed, 9 speed) whose [bolt circle diameter](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/55802/32314) matched the spider. Many end 11 and 12 speed cranksets have moved to 4-arm asymmetric designs, so you will need OEM replacements or chainrings that are designed to mate with the specific crankset.

Historically, most spiders have had 5 legs, and the crank arms and the spider were forged or molded (for carbon cranks) as one piece. With some cranks, the spider may be constructed separately, or the crankset may use chainrings that incorporate a spider. In either case, the spider or chainring would mount to a splined interface at the base of the crankarm.

[image: Image from trekstorecolumbus.com]

Some cranks use direct mount chainrings. Here, the spider is a part of the chainring, and the crankarms have a splined interface. This is discussed more on the article on [cranks](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/55802/32314).

Comment: Note: the study of spiders is [Arachnology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arachnology) :-)

Comment: Two suggestions: make the entry logically consistent, and add the apparently missing words. If my name is to be attached to such bosh then it looks like it's time to delete my account.

Answer (score 8):

### Lawyer Lips/ Lawyer Tabs

Bicycle forks with [quick-release](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/404#404) wheel mechanisms are often equipped with these. The intent is to make it less likely that the wheel will accidentally release if the quick-release lever is used improperly.

[image: lawyer lips] ([thanks to sk606](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2951/is-it-safe-to-remove-lawyer-tabs-on-a-carbon-fork) for the image)

In practice, they make it difficult to use the quick-release without unscrewing the [skewer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/4478#4478), making the quick-release harder to use.
[It is thought](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/gloss_l.html) that these were added to bikes [after a lawsuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_end#Lawyer_lips), which explains the name's origin. Professional cyclists would frequently file these off, as they may need to change wheels quickly during a race.

Disc brakes impose asymmetric torque on the hub, and they may cause skewers to be ejected from dropouts. Lawyer lips help prevent this. However, bikes with disc brakes now overwhelmingly use [thru-axles](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/41723/), which physically can't be ejected by torque.

Answer (score 8):

### Spoke

The spokes connect the [hub](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/3404#3404) of a wheel to its [rim](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/825#825). Spokes are secured to the rim by a spoke nipple. They insert into the hub at its flanges. Spoke count is the number of spokes in a wheel, and a higher spoke count usually means a stronger wheel that can handle more weight and abuse.

**Spoke tension** (the force with which the spokes are tightened) can be adjusted individually. This is part of the process of **truing a wheel**, ensuring the rim does not wobble side to side or up and down. This is particularly important with bikes that have low [tire clearance](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/44014/), but wheels that are trued are a benefit to any bike.

Almost all spokes are made of steel. In performance bikes, spokes are sometimes bladed or ovalized, which reduces the wheel's air resistance slightly.

Answer (score 7):

### Mixte, Step-Through Frame

A mixte is a frame with 3 sets of stays instead of the usual two. Riders don't have to raise their legs far to get them over the top tube. These frames were an advantage to women wearing dresses. The image below is courtesy of [Sheldon Brown's site](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/gloss_m.html#mixte).

[image]

The middle set of stays usually runs all the way to the head tube replacing the top tube, but on some mixte frames, the top tube is still a normal single tube. The traditional mixte has those axle-to-head stays straight, but there are also designs where they're bent to give an even lower standover height. They still retain the usual chain stays and seat stays. This design keeps the frame strong and doesn't require a longer seat post.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step-through_frame#Mixte) notes that the word *mixte* may come from the French word for *mixed* (as in mix of women's and men's styles) or *unisex*.

Comment: Note: This answer is from [this thread's answer](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2056/whats-the-definition-of-a-mixte/2057#2057) on Mixte bikes.

Answer (score 7):

### Chamois

The padding in a pair of cycling shorts. Traditionally this was made using chamois leather but is now usually a synthetic material.

[Chamois cream](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/562/8) can be used to prevent chafing while riding. With chamois leather, it can dry out and stiffen, so chamois cream is applied to the chamois to keep it supple. Modern chamois creams, however, are designed to be applied to the rider themselves rather than the synthetic padding.

Comment: And chamois cream is better known as "butt butter".

Answer (score 7):

### Power Meter

Power meters measure your power output. Power can be used to pace a ride, and to do structured interval training. [This StackExchange question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/30709/what-is-a-power-meter-and-why-do-i-need-one) has more in depth discussion. Power meters are ubiquitous in professional road racing. They have enabled better talent discovery and better and more targeted training. They can benefit many amateurs, but they are not *required* for satisfactory progress.

Alternatives include training by heart rate or by perceived effort. That said, heart rate will take several seconds to respond when you start an interval, and it will likewise take several seconds to come down when you stop an interval. Heart rate can be affected by fatigue. Some of the same criticisms hold for perceived effort. Power overcomes those disadvantages.

For structured training, riders estimate their functional threshold power (FTP). This is the maximum power you can sustain for some time, usually 30-70 minutes, and this usually corresponds to blood lactate levels (indicating anaerobic energy production) being steady as opposed to rising. Riders design intervals based on their FTP, e.g. warm up, ride 2x 15 minutes at 94-100% of FTP with a 7 minute rest, then cool down. More information on training zones (by FTP and heart rate) is [here](https://www.trainingpeaks.com/blog/power-training-levels/). Riders usually re-estimate their FTP during their season to keep their power targets in the correct zone.

### A brief history and basic technical information

Power meters use strain gauges to [measure the amount of deflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strain_gauge) or torque in a bike component, usually the crank or the pedal spindle, as you pedal. They also use a cadence sensor. Power = torque * cadence. [This answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/5612/how-do-bicycle-power-meters-work) has more detailed information on how power meters work physically. They transmit this information wirelessly to a computer, typically over Bluetooth or a sport-specific protocol called ANT+. The data files can be analyzed by a coach and uploaded to a training site like Strava. Note that power meters require a computer capable of communicating via ANT+ or Bluetooth to work, which is an additional expense. The older PowerTap shown below had a proprietary computer, but all current power meters work with most bike computers that have ANT+ or Bluetooth capability.

The first power meters were made by SRM (Schoberer Rad Metrik, a German company), and they were very expensive. As with many electronic goods, they have declined substantially in price in recent years. SRM power meters replaced the chainring spider, and several other power meters are still mounted here. Later power meters were mounted in hubs (e.g. PowerTap, now owned by SRAM, pictured below), the crank*arms*, or the pedal spindles, or a few less common arrangements. E-bikes also measure torque, a component of power, to determine how much assistance to provide.

[image: Image of power meter]

It is preferable to measure the total power generated by both legs, but some manufacturers offer left-only power meters to save costs. Power meters mounted at the crank spider, the hub, or on both crankarms or pedals will measure a rider's total power. Left-only power meters can be placed on the left crankarm or pedal spindle, or even on the right side. Left-only power is less accurate than total power. Also, if you have two independent power sensors on each side, you can measure the power balance between left and right, but it isn't clear if this is a significant benefit versus just knowing total power.

Power also enables virtual cycling environments like Zwift, where you simulate a rider's progress through a course and interactions between multiple riders based on their power and other inputs. Additionally, smart trainers can vary resistance at the flywheel to simulate gradient. Traditional wheel-on trainers can be used in this environment as well, but they can't simulate gradient. They can be used without a power meter, but this is less accurate.

### Maintenance

Power meters are sealed units. They don’t suffer wear in the same way that chains, cables, and other bike components do. If replaceable, the batteries will need to be replaced periodically. The strain gauges are delicate. Manufacturers will try to protect the strain gauge pod, but users should also take as much care as possible not to knock the pod unnecessarily.

Power meters may need to be periodically zeroed, like taring a weighing scale. You do this from your head unit or the phone app. Many newer power meters can auto zero. If you suspect a power meter is still reading wrongly, another step may be to calibrate the slope, I.e. the change in resistance with a known weight. This is usually done at the manufacturer, although some power meters enable users to do this. Smart trainers have a spindown function that is equivalent.

Smart trainers contain drive belts and cartridge bearings. These might wear out. Both belts and bearings tend to come in standard sizes. You could take the worn belt in to an auto parts store. For bearings, you can measure the physical size of the bearing; see the [entry on bearings](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/2758#2758) for more information. Removing them may take specialized tooling.

Reference:
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycling_power_meter)

Comment: @DanK I was thinking that SRM was a German company, and some wires got crossed in my head, and I made the rather amusing typo about Metrigear being a country that you caught. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

### Cage/Bottle Cage/Bottle Holder

Water bottle cages hold water bottles on a bike frame. Most cages attach to the frame via preinstalled threaded holes that are usually called bosses or mounts.

Most modern frames have at least two bottle cage mounts, one on the seat tube and one on the down tube. Some bikes, especially gravel bikes, have a third mount on the underside of the down tube. However, full suspension mountain bikes may have only one mount, as the suspension system can take up some room in the bike's main triangle.

On frames without mounts, bottle cage adapters might be able to strap around the tube. Alternatively, you may be able to drill a hole into the frame and put in a threaded insert called a riv nut. On metal frames with thicker tubing, this is likely to be safe, but it does create a stress riser which may later fail, and it will void any warranty.

A couple examples of cages are shown:

[image: Carbon Fibre]
[image: Aluminum]

For time trials and triathlons, there are also cage adapters that attach to the seat and provide mounting points for extra water bottle cages and spare tubes/inflators. A few new mounts place a water bottle between the extension of an aerobar set. (Image credit to Slowtwitch.com, a triathlon forum.)

[image: Behind the seat]
[image: Between the extensions]

Hydration vests like those made by Camelbak are an option for bikes without any cage mounts or to carry additional water. These may be less comfortable in hot weather. Hydration bladders can also be carried in frame packs that are strapped to the top tube; these packs frequently have exit ports for the hoses. Last, stem bags will strap to the stem and handlebar, and these can carry a bottle also.

Some bikes, mainly gravel bikes, may have mounts on the outsides of the fork blades. These multipurpose mounts can fit standard bottle cages or larger cargo cages. Some gravel and triathlon bikes may have a pair of bosses on the top tube near the stem. These may have the spacing typical of water bottle cages, but they are used for bolt-on boxes (aka Bento boxes) that hold snacks and equipment.

Comment: What? No picture of the most ridiculously priced bottle cage? It's actually come down in price. I used to be around $300 a couple years ago. http://www.amazon.com/Campagnolo-Super-Record-Carbon-Bottle/dp/B009CH0NDQ/

Answer (score 7):

### Mountain Bike

Often abbreviated as *MTB*. A bike with sturdier wheels (usually 29" or 27.5") and wider tires - at least 2" wide - meant for riding off-road. They are also characterized by flat handlebars, which offer better control in very rough terrain than drop bars, and they almost always have suspension. Modern MTBs also have very different frame geometry than road bikes, tending towards relatively upright positions.

Mountain bikes commonly come with front [suspension](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/64405/38558) (*hard tail*) or both front and rear [suspension](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/64405/38558) (*full suspension*). (*Rigid*) MTBs without any suspension do exist, and they require much more careful choice of lines. In the past, *soft tail* MTBs had a small, low-travel suspension where the seatstays joined the frame.

Comment: Any MTB riders able to improve this or the suspension article? I am unfamiliar with MTB subtypes, but they could be helpful to list. On suspension, I tried to list key concepts but am not certain if all were described correctly.

Answer (score 7):

**Dropout**

In the context of bicycles *dropouts* are a kind of [fork end](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_end), where the wheels are attached. Dropouts are employed on most bikes; on some bikes the axles pass through holes at the end of the forks ([through-axles](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/41723/7309)).

We often use *dropout* for any slot to hold the axle at the end of forks, but strictly speaking, a dropout is a fork end where the wheel can be removed from the frame without taking the chain off first. It's called a dropout because after loosening the [quick release](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/404/8273) or nuts the wheel will drop out when the bike is lifted off the ground. It is much quicker and easier to remove wheels with the bike the right way up than when the bike is upside down.

All front dropouts are vertical, and are usually also accompanied by [lawyer tabs](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/5584#5584) to mitigate the risk of improperly closing the [quick release skewer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/404#404). Most rear dropouts are as vertical. However, older bikes often have horizontal dropouts. The image below shows a Colnago horizontal dropout in a Surly frame; a typical example. It has adjustment screws and an integral [derailleur hanger](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/3665/8273).
[image: Colnago horizontal dropout in a Surly frame]

This [image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_end#/media/File:Horizontal_rear_dropout.jpg) (CC BY-SA) from Wikipedia shows a fork end that is *not* a dropout. The wheel cannot be removed without removing the chain.

[image: fork end]

Answer (score 7):

### Welded Frame

A frame made by melting the tubes it is built from at the joins, typically with a similar metal added as filler. For steel bikes, welding is more amenable to mass production than [brazing](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/37137/7044) or [lugs](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/37138/). Aluminum and titanium bikes have typically not used either of the other methods, although some frames have carbon tubes bonded to metal lugs. Welding is typically done under an inert gas. Framebuilders must prevent contamination at the welds from oxygen or other materials. If this is not done, the weld can fail later on.

[image: welded frame joints]

Answer (score 7):

### Pump Peg

A **pump peg** is a small protrusion on a bike frame which is intended to facilitate the mounting of a "frame pump". Depending on the style of the frame, the peg may be positioned to allow the pump to fit on the underside of the top tube (of a standard diamond frame) or on the trailing side of the down tube.  The peg is designed to mate with a corresponding hole in the end of the pump. The pump is spring loaded, and the expansion of the spring holds the pump in place.

Some schemes have a peg at each end, while others rely on the other end of the pump being wedged into the V formed by the top tube and seat tube.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

**Dropper Posts**

Dropper posts are more commonly found on mountain bikes and on some gravel bikes. They allow the rider to quickly lower their saddle height, and thus their center of gravity. This is useful for very steep descents, where you might otherwise feel like you are going over the handlebars. You actuate the dropper using either a remote lever mounted on the bars or an actuator under the saddle (entry level models).

They are also appearing on upper versions of electric urban (e-)bikes, where they offer other benefits: easier to get in and out the saddle or to share a bike between people of different heights.

Cable-operated and hydraulic-operated designs exist. The cable or hose can be routed either internally or externally to the frame (as the frame allows). For mountain bikes, a small release lever is fitted to the handlebar. For gravel bikes, the left brifter can be used for the the dropper post (1x transmissions only). SRAM's AXS system can actuate a dropper post wirelessly, usually from the the left shift paddle.

[image: dropper post]
<sub>(source: [evanscycles.com](https://static.evanscycles.com/production/components/seatposts/product-image/969-638/thomson-elite-dropper-seatpost-black-EV187905-8500-1.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Maybe we don't need to list manufacturers in these wikis, we can't list them all and makes can go obsolete, we want the entries to be as enduring as possible

Comment: Excellent!   Want to add an entry for "seatpost" too?  We don't have one listed.  Could be worth adding why a MTB rider might want to lower their saddle, without stopping.

Comment: I concur with Swifty, and I’ve deleted the manufacturer list. If others disagree, I can revert. I changed the entry on power meters to delete the list of manufacturers I added, but for historical interest i mentioned SRM, the first company to make a commercial power meter. If there’s interest in that sort of history here, I would vote for adding that.

Comment: Imagine rocking up two years late for an edit :D

Answer (score 6):

### Hose Clamp

#### A.K.A. Jubilee Clip

A ratcheting clamp often used to attach items to a bicycle fork or handlebars.

[image: Flashlight attached to flat handlebars with a series of hose clamps.]

[Flashlight attached to handlebars with a series of hose clamps.](http://www.flickr.com/photos/neilfein/1013386555/)

[Jubilee Clip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jubilee_Clip) on Wikipedia

Comment: I see how the clamp goes around the torch, but how does it attach to the bars? Is there a second clamp, or does it twist around?

Comment: There's a second clamp.

Comment: Hose clamps can cut into paint an even metal if they're tight enough. You can stick a strip of old inner tube under the clamp to prevent this (and to provide better grip).

Answer (score 6):

**Cable Pull**

Many brakes and most derailleurs are actuated by pulling cables. *Cable pull* is how far the cable moves when the brake lever is pulled, or a shift lever is actuated.

For brakes, there are two main standards, short or conventional pull and long or V brake pull. Road bikes have tended to use short pull levers, although current Shimano road brakes operate on a slightly different cable pull than other brands. For mountain bikes, cable-actuated brakes have tended to use long pull. This means that mountain bike V-brakes will not work correctly with road levers and vice versa, although cable pull adapters may be available.

For indexed gears each groupset manufacturer will specify its own cable pull per shift (i.e. each click at the shifter), as well as how far the derailleur travels laterally per shift (i.e. the shift ratio or actuation ratio). Thus, shifters and derailleurs cannot generally be mixed across component manufacturers. Non-indexed (friction) shifters can generally be mixed, provided they have enough total cable pull.

[image: cable pull diagram]

Comment: Sorry about the edit war. Short pull brakes are *not* Shimano specific, friction shifters work if there's enough cable pull.

Answer (score 6):

### Brazed Frame

#### see also [lugged frame](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/37138/33084) and [welded frame](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/37139#37139)

A method of joining frame parts together by melting brass into the joins between frame tubes. Frames can be fillet brazed or use lugs, which are extra, normally cast metal, parts that the frame tubes slot into before brazing. Lugs make building a strong frame easier, provided you have exactly the right lug for the situation. Fillet brazing offers more freedom but also more skill is required to produce a strong joint. Some people think that there is an aesthetic benefit over welding, as brazing, like some welding techniques, do not leave a rough bead of material at the joints.

Shown is part of a fillet brazed steel frame, with the grey steel contrasting with the copper-coloured brass.

[image: fillet brazed frame]

The most common alternative method is [welding](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/37139#37139), where the parent metal is melted and the same or a very similar metal is added as filler. Welding is generally stronger, faster and can be automated but brazing or soldering are sometimes preferred for DIY or aesthetic reasons.

Answer (score 6):

## Thru Axles / Through Axles

Through axles (TAs) are large-diameter threaded fasteners that secure the bike's wheels to the frame and fork, serving the same role as [Quick Release Skewers](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/404#404). They originated on mountain bikes because QR axles were occasionally breaking during extreme riding, and the forces generated by disc brakes can cause wheels to come out of the dropouts if their quick release is not secured properly. Since then, they have been used on many road bikes too.

Thru axles insert into the dropout on one side, pass through the hub's hollow axle, and then thread into female threads on the fork and frame on the other side. A frame and fork must be designed to use thru axles, and you generally can’t retrofit a quick release frame to take TAs (with the exception of some frames that use modular/interchangeable dropouts.)

The through axle is the upper device in the following image:

[image: from http://cdn.mos.bikeradar.imdserve.com/images/news/2014/02/14/1392416431992-ecxclyd8c6n5-700-80.jpg]

The dropouts on a through axle frame or fork are "closed" as opposed to the "open" dropouts used by QR systems — as this image shows, there is a solid ring of metal surrounding the black thru axle and threaded insert.

[image: From http://fcdn.mtbr.com/attachments/beginners-corner/789715d1365723144-need-help-new-bike-assembly-thru-axle-axle-pic.jpg]

Contrast with [Quick Release](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/404#404)

### Advantages

The purported advantages of thru axles are:

- Increased stiffness when turning because of the larger diameter hub interface and higher clamping force. They can also be stronger in shear as they are no longer restricted by the 9 or 10mm diameter of a QR open dropout.
- Thru axles enable more consistent placement of the wheel compared to open dropouts and quick releases. Because it is possible to secure the wheel askew in the dropouts in a quick release setup, brake rub may occur due to the misalignment because disc brakes have tight tolerances regarding alignment. The repeatable nature of the closed dropout system minimizes this issue.
- Torque from braking can no longer eject the front wheel because the axle is encapsulated by the dropouts.
- Shock load is shared between both fork legs more evenly.
- Less rotational torsion on the fork leg that the brake caliper attaches to.

### Replacing a Thru Axle / Sizing

As of today (2021), through axle diameters are as follows:

- 12mm for **rear** wheels
- 12mm for **road bike** front wheels
- 15mm for **XC/trail/enduro** mountain bike **front** wheels
- 20mm for **downhill** mountain bike **front** wheels

Exceptions are common though, such as 15mm front TAs on earlier thru axle road bikes.

Unlike quick releases, thru axles tend to be unique to each bike. Two bikes may have the same over-locknut distance (e.g. 142mm for road bikes), but their dropouts are likely to differ in thickness. The thread pitch is also a variable (the spacing between adjacent thread peaks, e.g. 1 or 1.5mm). Some suspension designs such as Trek's ABP necessitate extra-long axles as well. Do not try to use axles differing from the intended specifications to avoid damaging one's bicycle and potentially incurring personal injury.

Riders can get replacement thru axles from the bike's manufacturer, fork manufacturer, or from aftermarket brands. Specifications to be aware of include:

- Diameter
- Total length
- Length of the threaded portion
- Thread pitch

#### Retention Mechanism

Through axles are available with a variety of retention methods. These include hexagonal tool fittings for use with Allen wrenches, integrated handles, detachable handles, cam levers (much like those on QRs), and specialty designs such as Cervelo's RAT system. Additionally, forks and frames may have extra features such as pinch bolts that further secure the through axle. Each design balances a different ratio between security, stiffness, weight, sleekness (handles can catch on trail debris), and convenience, so it is up to the rider to decide what design works best for them.

### Final Notes

Note the distinction between through axles and the threaded axles often found on childrens' and utility bicycles. While both have large-diameter threads, threaded axles are integral to the hub, while through axles are entirely separate from the fork and frame. Additionally, threaded axles use open dropouts, unlike the closed dropouts used by TA designs. Lastly, threaded axles are tightened using separate nuts, while TAs are tightened directly into the frame or fork.

Answer (score 6):

**Bonk**

An expression used by cyclists to describe sudden fatigue or loss of energy while exercising. Also known as crashing, blowing up, or running out of steam/gas/fuel, or empty tank. The phenomenon applies to all endurance sports. In running, it may be called hitting the wall. Bonking is distinct from merely being tired due to lack of sleep or from a higher than normal training load. Subjectively, it can be quite unpleasant to bonk! There can be cognitive effects as well as physical ones.

Athletes bonk when they deplete their muscle glycogen stores. Glycogen is a form of glucose (a simple carbohydrate) that our bodies use as fuel. It is stored in the muscles and liver. This can be reversed by eating immediately, preferably foods high in easily-digestible sugars. Water alone will not reverse a bonk. Bonking can be prevented entirely by eating regularly during a race or training, although this is generally not a concern in sessions under 2 hours. Carbohydrate loading before an event may also make bonking less likely. During an event, you can consume carbohydrates in sports drinks, in pre-made energy chews, gels, or bars, or via real food.

Comment: You've edited out the point that this is an unpleasant result; an experience to be avoided wherever possible.  Its more than simply being tired.

Answer (score 5):

## Chain guard/Chain cover

It's a frame, usually made of plastic or metal, that covers the entire length of the chain or only the upper part, mainly for protecting the rider from the dirt and lubricant on the chain, but can also protect the chain itself.

[image: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bike_chain_guard_full.JPG]

[image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/Bike_chain_guard_part.JPG/320px-Bike_chain_guard_part.JPG]

Answer (score 5):

### Lugged Frame

#### also lugs

A method of frame-building where at least the major joints consist of frame tubes inserted into castings (the lugs). Lugs are often associated with steel frames. Steel lugs are hand-made by bending and filing rather than casting. Lugged frames are normally brazed, but can also be soldered (with lead or silver rather than brass) and occasionally glued (the Windcheetah trike used glued aluminium, for example).

Historically, lugged frames were very common, and many classic steel frames were built this way. Lugged construction in mass-produced bikes of any material is rare, and most modern steel frames are welded. Another alternative construction method for steel frames is [fillet brazing](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/37137#37137).

[image: classic Italian lugged frame]

A minority of carbon frames are lugged, for example the Colnago C-64 (link from Cyclingweekly).

[image]

It is also possible to bond carbon tubes to metal lugs. For example, the Trek 2300 frame used carbon tubes bonded to aluminum lugs.

Answer (score 5):

**Tyre Clearance** or **Tire Clearance**

Wider tires at a lower pressure are more comfortable than narrower ones, and they often have no rolling resistance penalty. For riders interested in fitting wider tires, many bikes will state the maximum tire size the frame and fork have room to fit. For example, 2020-2021 gravel bikes can typically fit at least 40mm tires, and many 2020-2021 road bikes can fit as much as a 32mm tire. There is often some wiggle room, because tires' *actual* width can vary slightly from their nominal size (i.e. the size printed on the sidewall). This can be due to manufacturing variations, but tires will get larger as the rim's internal width grows, and bike manufacturers do not know what rim size their bikes will be used with.

On road bikes, manufacturers typically aim for at least 4mm clearance on all sides of the tire, measured at the narrowest part of the fork or the rear of the bike. Off-road bikes should aim for more clearance than this to enable mud or dirt build up. The photograph below illustrates insufficient tire clearance between the arch of the brake caliper and the fork crown, i.e. there isn't enough vertical clearance under the brake arch. You also need to check horizontal clearance at the fork legs, seat stays, and chain stays.

[image]

If you have too little clearance, then if dirt or mud accumulates, it will abrade through your paint and possibly through the frame itself. A deeper, illustrated [discussion is here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/44010/what-does-tire-clearance-mean/44013). Note that if you don't have measuring calipers, you can use allen wrenches to check your current tire clearance, i.e. try to fit a 4mm allen wrench between your tire and frame.

Some aerodynamic road or time trial bikes are designed for minimal clearance between the back tire and the frame. They may have cutouts in the seat tube, or a curved seat tube. A similar arrangement is also possible in front.

Comment: I am surprised that a smaller gap should be aerodynamically better, which is also not explained in the linked article. Could someone explain (here or there), there must surely be a lower limit?

Comment: @PJTraill This might be better in [chat], but in brief, the tyre creates a substantial circular airflow while spinning.  Test by spinning up the back wheel of your bike while its off the ground, then put a hand near the fast moving tyre.  Its much worse on a MTB knobbly, but even a smooth road tyre as pictured will create a draught. The tight clearance helps reduce the two airflows meeting head on - if anything the rear airflow should help push the bike and the airflow from the front should be smoothly diverted to the sides, rather than meeting and being choppy air.  Like a splitter on a car.

Comment: @PJTraill the lower limit would be touching - if your tyre rubs your bike then that's wasted watts, and it will wear out the tyre and the rubbed point, which is also bad for your bike.  Since all bikes have some amount of flex, the wheel will have some slight movement requiring space to prevent rubbing.  That's the lower limit.    Anyway - do consider joining the [chat].

Answer (score 5):

**BCD (Bolt Circle Diameter)**

As [Wolf Tooth Components](https://www.wolftoothcomponents.com/pages/how-to-measure-bolt-circle-diameter-bcd) describes,

> "Bolt Circle Diameter or BCD is the diameter of the circle that goes
> through the center of all of the bolts on your chainring.  On bicycle
> chainring this dimension is usually measured in millimeters.  It is
> critical to know the BCD of your crankset when you are selecting a new
> chainring for your bike."

[image: BCD illustration]

If the BCD is not written on the chainring, it must be found another way. One method is to compare the chainring directly with another one of known BCD, or against a scaled reference drawing. Each BCD has a minimum chainring size, e.g. for a 110mm BCDs 33 teeth are the smallest chainring size possible on most cranks without interference with other parts of the crank.

Alternatively, the distance between the centres of adjacent holes/bolts is measured and this value read into a [look-up](https://www.wolftoothcomponents.com/pages/how-to-measure-bolt-circle-diameter-bcd) [table](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/cribsheet-bcd.html) (links to two examples from Wolf Tooth and Sheldon Brown) to find out the BCD. This can be done for 3, 4 and 5 bolt designs, meaning the BCD can be measured without removing the chain ring.

For a symmetrical, four bolt arrangement, measuring BCD is trivial with the use of a caliper, as seen below. The BCD of a chainring can similarly be measured directly with a ruler when the chainring is removed and the crank is not an obstruction. For many drop bar bikes bikes, 5-bolt arms with 130mm and 110mm BCDs were common, with many manufacturers having gone to proprietary and often asymmetrical 4-arm designs or direct mount cranks. MTB BCDs are smaller and more varied, and direct mount cranks have become more common here as well.

[image: Measuring BCD on a symmetrical four bolt design]

More recent 4-bolt road cranks are an exception. Many of them have 110mm BCDs, but they space the crankarms unevenly. If you are looking for a third-party chainring for these cranks, the manufacturer will state which brand the rings are compatible with (and sometimes, which models, e.g. Shimano R9100 and R8000 vs 9000 and 6800). Alternatively, some cranks are direct mount, i.e. the chainring is made with the spider and bolts to a splined interface shared with the crankarm. These chainrings will state which interfaces they are compatible with, e.g. Praxis or SRAM/Quarq.

Comment: Typical/common sizes would also be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

### Chainsuck

*Chainsuck happens when the bicycle chain fails to disengage from the teeth of a chainring—usually during a shift—and wraps back up and around the chainring.*

[image]

Citation and image from: http://reviews.mtbr.com/workbench-how-to-un-suck-your-chainsuck
See also: [What causes chain suck?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/7107/32314)

Answer (score 4):

**Stack Height**

The stack height of a headset is the vertical space taken up by a headset, and the  stem when using a threadless headset. It's the difference between the headtube length and the fork steerer length needed to be able to use that headset with that fork and headtube.

http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/fork-column-length-and-sizing

http://sheldonbrown.com/gloss_st-z.html

Answer (score 4):

**Single-speed**

This means a bike that has exactly one rear cog, and cannot change gear.  Very similar to a fixed-gear bike except a single-speed has a freewheel mechanism to allow coasting, i.e. riding along without pedalling.

Compare with [Fixed-Gear](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/271/8273).

Answer (score 4):

### Play

Play means unwanted movement in a system. It can be caused when one or more moving mechanical parts do not fit as specified. This can be caused when manufactured parts are out of the specified [tolerances](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/81703/38270), e.g. one part is too small.

In some cases, play can develop if parts were in tolerance to begin with but they wear excessively. For example, older rear derailleurs may wear to the point where the pivots are sloppy, which decreases shifting quality.

Alternatively, some systems need to be tightened down to avoid play. For example, headsets need to have their top caps tightened, or the steerer tube will rock fore to aft. Some cranksets and hubs will have lateral play if not tightened. This is called adjusting the preload of the system, and is discussed under [bearings](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/2758#2758).

Opposites: Tight/stiff/fine +tolerances, precise.
Synonyms or similar concepts: Slop, wear, wobbly, loose, janky, worn, worn out.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

### Rim Tape

For clincher type rims and tires with inner tubes: tape applied to the inside of the wheel rim to protect the inner tube from sharp edges and the ends of the spokes and spoke nipples, which would otherwise abrade the tube and cause punctures.

For tubeless clincher rims and tires: tubeless rim tape covers the spoke holes and seals the inside of the rim. The tape aids in keeping the system airtight. Thus, rim tapes made specifically for tubed clinchers, like cloth tape, will not work as tubeless rim tape. However, tubeless rims with tubeless tape can still accept inner tubes. In fact, riders with tubeless tires will often carry a tube for emergencies.

Tubular rims do not use rim tape in the same manner as clincher rims. Tubular tires themselves are an airtight unit. However, some cyclists use tubular glue tape in place of liquid glue, or as a supplement to glue.

Answer (score 4):

### Axle

Quote and image from [Sheldon Brown's Bicycle Glossary](https://sheldonbrown.com/gloss_an-z.html#axle):

> The shaft at the middle of a bearing. There is some controversy as to
> whether "axle" or "spindle" should be used in particular contexts. The
> distinction is based on whether the axle/spindle is stationary, as
> that in a hub, or rotates, as that in a bottom bracket. There have
> been bitter flame wars fought in magazine letters columns over this
> point.

[image: axle]

The image above is a hub axle. This hub takes cup and cone bearings, and the balls are in contact with the cones. The locknuts adjust the preload, I.e. how ‘tight’ the hub is. Too much or too little preload will damage the bearings. Axles for cartridge bearing hubs omit the cones, and there are usually endcaps rather than adjustable locknuts. The other common axle on bikes is attached to the crank or bottom bracket, although this is often called a spindle by convention.

[See questions about axle](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/axle)

Answer (score 4):

### Coaster Brake

> (a.k.a **foot brake, or pedal brake.**)
>
> A coaster brake is a special rear hub for a bicycle, which performs two functions:
>
> - It allows the bicycle to roll without forcing the pedals to turn.
>     This is the "coaster" part. It is similar in function to a freewheel
>     , but uses a different sort of mechanism to accomplish it.
> - It is also a brake, operated by turning the pedals backwards.
>
> Coaster brakes were invented in the 1890s, and have continued to be popular in some areas to this day.

Source: https://sheldonbrown.com/coaster-brakes.html

---

[image: coaster brake hub]

A video explaining the internal mechanism of a coaster brake:

[See questions about coaster brakes](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coaster)

Answer (score 4):

## Q-Factor

### Related: Stance width

Q-factor is the distance (in millimetres) between the outside faces of your crank arms. It is one component of your *stance width*, which is the Q-factor plus the horizontal distance from the outside face of each crankarm to the center of the pedal. In common speech, people may conflate Q-factor with stance width.

The term may originate as a [contraction of “quack factor”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor_(bicycles)), originating with Grant Peterson, an engineer formerly at Bridgestone Cycles. A larger Q-factor, all else equal, means that your pedals are further away from the bike's center line, and therefore your feet are further apart. The diagram below illustrates Q-factor, and it also shows how Q-factor is distinct from chainline.

[image: Edited version of previous pic from https://electricbikereview.com/forum/attachments/bicycle-q-factor-jpg.21791/]

Ultimately, when you are pedaling, you want your feet to be moving straight up and down. A stance width that is too wide or too narrow can make your knees depart from this ideal path, e.g. they might wander outwards at the top of the pedal stroke. This can eventually cause knee problems.

Q-factor is an inherent property of your crankset and your bicycle. Road cranksets have Qs around 146mm, with gravel-specific groupsets having about 5mm wider Q than this. MTB cranksets have Qs of at least 160mm for non-Boost bikes, and wider for bikes that use Boost spacing. MTBs have wider Qs in large part to enable sufficient tire clearance. There are generally few options to adjust the Q-factor, and besides this cranks are expensive.

However, there are many options to adjust stance width. The picture below shows a pedal extender, which usually adds 20mm on each side to the stance width. It is usually safe to add 1-2mm washers to a standard pedal, although going further is not recommended as not enough threads on the pedal spindle will engage. Most pedal manufacturers use 52-53mm as their default pedal width, but many offer axles that are 4mm longer than standard. Last, you can move your cleats laterally on their mounting points, usually by about 2-3mm from the centerline. Aside from moving cleats, options to *reduce* stance width tend to be fewer, but fewer riders need these.

[image]

Note - Q-factor is NOT measured from the bike centerline because some frames are asymmetric.

Comment: I'm not sure I get this correctly: "Q-factor can be increased by adding extenders, or using wider pedals." -- But in the diagram I see that Q factor is not influenced by pedal width.

Comment: @RobertLee fair point - how's that edit?  Basically the extender is a short bolt, with another thread in the end that effectively makes the pedal's shaft longer / have more stick-out.  Downside, more leverage on the threads because its now a longer lever.  I only drew one extender, normally they'd be fitted in pairs, but variation in people might make fitting a single appropriate, perhaps their hips are not symmetrical.  A bike fit would show up differences like that.

Comment: To @RobertLee's point, perhaps the title should be changed to Q-factor and Stance Width. The first sentence says Q-factor is the distance between the outer faces of each crankarm. The 3rd sentence says it can be increased by adding pedal spacers. Those two contradict, actually - if we take the first sentence, the only way to get a different Q-factor is different crankarms.

Comment: @WeiwenNg I see your point, but as per picture, adding spacers effectvely makes the outer face of the crank arm further out from the bike's center line, which is exactly where Q factor is measured to.

Comment: If you attach the extender to the pedal first, you can say it increases pedal width. If you attach it to the crank first, it increases crank arm distance from centerline. Can't we instead keep 3 separate measures to avoid ambiguity: Q-Factor without any extenders, effective (i.e excluding threads) extender width, effective pedal width? What is Q-Factor useful for? What does it tell us? Besides bike fitting, I think it concerns crank-chainstay clearance too. By adding an extender you won't increase chainstay clearance.

Comment: Stance Width alone is also ambiguous: is it wide cranks + narrow pedals, or is it narrow cranks + wide pedals? It's a big difference I think. With wider pedals you can place your feet farther or closer however you want; with narrow pedals, even if the Stance Width is the same, you are more limited.

Comment: "Q-factor can only be reduced by changing the cranks for narrower ones, which increases the possibility of heel/shoe strike on the crankset or chain or front derailleur." Can't it also be reduced by a shorter BB spindle (square tapered type  for example)?

Comment: @RobertLee with square taper cranks, and clearance permitting, you're correct. Almost no current performance bikes use square taper cranks, so their Q-factor can't be changed thusly.

Comment: @Criggie I feel this is missing one of the most vital pieces of information about Q-factor: 

The "Q" stands for "quack", a reference to the wide stance and waddling gait of ducks.

Something I was told many years ago and assumed was probably true, now validated on Wikipedia with a proper source - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor_(bicycles)#cite_note-3

Comment: @RobertLee Per the discussion we had, I've just gone and added references to stance width in the article. In any case, it's my sense that in common speech, people tend to conflate Q-factor and stance width. Furthermore, it is actually quite hard to adjust Q-factor. You may be able to change your crankset, but options with different Qs tend to be scarce, unless you count moving from a road group to a gravel group, or edge cases like the eeWings All-Road crankset, which has a 160mm Q and costs over US$1k (!!!). Options to adjust your stance width are more plentiful.

Comment: @WeiwenNg yeah effectively to the rider, stance and q factor are the same thing because your feet are further apart.  The difference is whether the width comes from the crank or the pedal axle, but the pedal body gets pushed further outboard.  Pedal extenders are much cheaper than cranksets!  I've recently added pedal extenders to a particularly narrow-feeling 80's bike, and it feels substantially better.

Answer (score 3):

**Axle Nuts**

An older method of holding a wheel into dropouts.

Compare with [Through Axles](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/41723/19705) or with [Quick Release/QR](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/404/19705)

[image]

This image also shows a retention washer with a hooked retainer.

[image]

Some particularly vintage wheel wingnuts.  These could have been on a racer, or used so the rider didn't need a tool.

[image]

Vertical view showing the nuts on either side of the wheel, and how the axle and dropouts are organised.

Comment: It will take a thief slightly more time, and will need a wrench, to unscrew the nuts and steal your wheel; one small advantage over quick release types, perhaps.

Answer (score 3):

**Bidon. Aka water bottle.**

[image: A typical bidon.]

Specifically designed to securely fit into bottle cages on the frame.  Generally hold 500-750ml (22-26oz) of water; litre bottles that fit cages are becoming more common, electrolyte solution or similar depending on rider preference to provide hydration during a ride. Bidon is the French term and is likely to be understood by road cyclists.

[See here for more](https://www.cyclingweekly.com/news/latest-news/icons-cycling-bidon-230679), Cycling Weekly article.

Answer (score 3):

**Suspension Systems**

Suspension allows the fork and/or the rear triangle to compress when a rider goes over a bump. This helps the wheels maintain traction in rough terrain and improves rider comfort. Suspension seatposts and stems are also available for rider comfort, but they don't assist with traction.

On road and most gravel bikes, the tires deliver sufficient suspension for the terrain these bikes traverse. In contrast, mountain bikes are designed to excel on rougher terrain. Almost all MTBs have at least front suspension, aside from those who elect to run rigid MTBs. The image below shows a sample of suspension forks.

**Front suspension**
[image: Fox Front Forks]

Typically, in Cross Country (XC), All Mountain (AM), Enduro or Aggressive Hard Tail frames (ie, those that have no rear suspension), front fork travel can range from 100mm to 160mm travel dependent on the frame geometry.

Modern forks offer a lockout (also available as a remote lever lockout, mounted to the handlebar) which allows the rider to quickly disable the fork travel. This is useful when riding on road to provide a rigid platform so as not to unduly waste rider effort.

**Rear Shock**

[image: Rear shock]
<sub>(source: [bouncecycles.co.uk](https://bouncecycles.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Fox-Forx-DHX-Air-5.0-e1428489119195.jpg))</sub>

Typical rear shock travel for mountain bikes ranges from 100mm to 200mm depending on the frame discipline with Down Hill (DH) bikes offering the most travel (+/- 200mm front and rear).

Previously, some bikes had a soft-tail suspension, with a shock unit placed where the seat stays attached to the seat tube. These typically had smaller travel.

Similarly to front suspension, some rear shocks offer a travel lock out which limits the rear shock travel, useful for riding on tarmac or more predictable surfaces.

**Some key concepts**
Suspension systems can be sprung by:

- Coil-sprung shocks use a large metal spring – normally steel – positioned outside the telescopic tubes that make up the shock body.
- Air-sprung shocks meanwhile feature a compressed air spring inside the body of the shock.
- Elastomer-based systems rely on rubber or another elastic material to compress. These typically offer less travel than coil shocks, but are lighter.

Some key terms are:

- Travel: the maximum distance which the suspension can travel. Very roughly speaking, more enables you to handle rougher terrain.
- Bottom out and top out: When you hit a bump, if the suspension system reaches the limit of its travel, it has bottomed out. If you have too many harsh bottom outs, you need more suspension and you also risk damaging the suspension. Conversely, a suspension system will *rebound* after taking a hit, and top outs occur when it hits its travel limit on the rebound. Suspensions may have rubber bumpers inside the suspension chambers to prevent damage if it bottoms out.
- Sag: When you sit on the bike, your weight compresses the suspension. This is called sag. Suspension systems can be tuned for riders of different weights. Notably, suspension manufacturers may recommend that you set the damping such that the sag is a certain percent of the total travel.
- Compression damping and rebound damping: You can adjust suspension, e.g. by adding air pressure, to adjust its feel while compressing. More compression damping means more resistance as the fork compresses, which feels firmer. You can similar adjust the amount of rebound damping.

**Maintenance**

Suspension systems require periodic maintenance. Riders should wipe their fork stanchions, or the metal legs, after each ride, and inspect for scratches. Periodic higher-level maintenance may involve replacing the fork seals, which keep dirt out of the suspension chamber, lubrication, possibly rebuilding springs and replacing bushings.

Newer cyclists riding only on paved paths should consider foregoing a suspension system. The prime reason is that suspension is not necessary for this use case, and furthermore a suspension fork requires maintenance and will eventually seize without maintenance - at which point it is dead weight that you paid extra for.

Answer (score 3):

## Derailleur or derailer

Derailleurs enable bicycles to use multiple gears. The word's origin is [French](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/derailer.html), but in English the accent mark is omitted. It is sometimes spelled derailer.

[Before derailleurs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_bicycle#Technical_innovations), bicycles [often had](https://bikeraceinfo.com/photo-galleries/derailleurs-1.html) one gear mounted to either side of the rear hub, and riders would stop and then flip their rear wheel around to change gears. Derailleurs enabled riders to change gears while riding by "de railing" the chain from one cog to the next. By enabling multiple gears, they significantly increased the range of terrain that bicycles could cover.

Derailleurs [were first invented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derailleur_gears) in the late 19th century. Early versions [used rods](https://bikeraceinfo.com/photo-galleries/derailleurs-1.html) to push the chain onto different cogs. Tullio Campagnolo [played a major role](https://janheine.wordpress.com/2014/07/01/a-reappraisal-of-tullio-campagnolo/) in the development of modern derailleurs, having commercialized a successful version in 1949.

**Maintenance**

Almost all derailleurs are actuated by shift cables. Because cables stretch a bit over time, new bikes require a minor adjustment after a few weeks' riding. While there is a bit of a learning curve, it is possible to adjust your derailers yourself, a process outlined later. The shift cables and housing are the main wear parts in derailer drivetrains, as they will accumulate contamination over time. Very active riders may replace these as often as annually. In many cases, poor shifting can be rectified by changing the cables.

The Delrin jockey wheels are the other common wear part on the rear derailer, but the replacement interval is much longer. If you can't find an OEM replacement, you should be able to find an aftermarket one.

The rear derailer is mounted to the frame with a [derailer hangar](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/3665#3665), usually replaceable and made of aluminum. Even a minor drop can bend the hangar, which will affect shifting. However, the hangar is designed to break before anything more valuable, i.e. the derailer itself or the frame, does.

**Key concepts and terms**

- For front derailleurs, *capacity* is the maximum chainring difference it can shift, e.g. the common compact double crankset with a 50t big ring and a 34t small ring needs a capacity of 50-34 = 16. Modern Shimano and Campagnolo road front derailleurs are rated for that capacity, with SRAM using a smaller capacity deliberately. For triple cranks, use the difference in tooth counts between the big and smallest ring.
- For rear derailleurs, capacity is the difference above, *plus* the difference between the largest and smallest cog. For example, with the compact crankset above and a 11-34 cassette, the required rear derailleur capacity would be 16 + (34-11) = 16 + 23 = 39. This is the exact capacity of Shimano's R7000 and R8000 *long cage* rear derailleurs.
- Rear derailleurs may be offered in several different *cage lengths*. Longer cages have higher capacity. In theory, they should shift a bit more slowly than short cage derailleurs, but the difference may be noticeable. There is often a *maximum* size for the largest cog, e.g. short cage Shimano R7000 and R8000 rear derailleurs are rated for cassettes with up to 30t big cogs, which means that 11-32 and 11-34 cassettes are out of manufacturer specification.
- However, you can commonly exceed the stated capacity slightly. Shifting will be worse than if you run equipment in spec, and the quality of shifting should decline as you go further from spec. However, not all bikes will be affected the same way, and not all cyclists will notice.

**Alternatives to derailleurs**

[Internally geared hubs](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/1728#1728) (IGHs) are an alternative system. The rear hub contains all the gears and shifting mechanisms. These are much less vulnerable to contamination than traditional drivetrains, but they have slightly greater drivetrain friction. Some IGHs may use drive belts rather than chains. Note that drive belts are not compatible with traditional derailers. IGHs are sealed from the elements, although some main require periodic lubrication through a port. [This answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/20593/internal-gear-hub-maintenance) discusses more. Gearboxes are similar to IGHs, but the gearing mechanism is mounted at the bottom bracket.

As another alternative, one can ride a single speed or fixed gear bicycle, both of which have only one or two gears (the second gear, if present, would be mounted on the opposite side of the rear hub).

**Recent developments**

The number of cogs on the rear wheel has increased with time, and the gear ranges available have become a lot wider. On road bikes, this has mostly led to the demise of the triple crankset.

Modern mountain bikes have switched to 1x (pronounced one-by) drivetrains, dropping the front derailer entirely. This has enabled wider tires and improvements in the rear suspension. 1x systems are becoming more common on gravel bikes, but they are not widespread on road bikes as of late 2021. On a 2x drivetrain, if you drop the chainring to the inside, you can often recover by shifting to the big ring and pedaling (and the reverse if you drop the chain to the outside). 1x drivetrains do not have this option. They use 1x-specific chainrings with narrow-wide teeth, i.e. the teeth alternate between narrow and wide teeth to retain the chain more firmly. They also incorporate clutches in the rear derailers, which reduce the amount of chain slap on rough terrain.

Electronically actuated drivetrains have become popular as a high-end option as well. These do away with metal shift cables entirely. They also have potential for adaptive cycling, as you can actuate shifts with a lot less finger force and you could set up the system for one-handed operation. However, they are considerably more expensive than mechanical shifting. In principle, derailleurs could also be hydraulically actuated, but no major drivetrain company has yet proposed a system.

### You can adjust your derailers yourself!

**NB - Before any rear derailleur adjustment, first ensure the [derailleur hanger](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/1728#1728) is aligned correctly**

Adjustment may seem intimidating at first. However, it can be learned easily, and it will improve with practice.

Both front and rear derailleurs are adjustable by high (H) and low (L) limit screws. The limit screws control how far the rear derailleur can move in the largest (high limit) and smallest (low limit) cogs. At each limit, you should aim to center the derailleur on the smallest (low limit) and largest (high limit) cogs respectively. For the front derailleur, the high limit refers to the big chainring (i.e. higher gearing).

In addition, rear derailleurs have a cable tension adjuster. This accounts for the fact that cables stretch after some use. When facing the rear derailleur from the rear of the bike, if you turn the adjusting knob, this loosens the cable. It may help to remember that as your shifters pull cable, the derailleurs move towards the larger cog<sup>note</sup> or chainring. When the rear derailleur isn't moving far enough towards the next larger cog, it may fail to shift, so adding cable tension (i.e. turn knob anti-clockwise) will help it move further. (This is different from the limit screws, which control how far the derailleur *can* move, and for the rear that only applies to the smallest and largest cogs.)

Last, rear derailleurs also have a screw to control how close the top pulley is to the cogs (the B-tension screw). If the top pulley is too far away from the cogs, this should reduce shift quality. If it is too close, you may be unable to shift to the largest cog, as the chain will rub. Manufacturers typically specify an acceptable distance. Park Tools also has written guides (for the [rear](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/rear-derailleur-adjustment) and [front](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/front-derailleur-adjustment) derailleurs respectively), and their YouTube channel also has videos with explanations.

The following shows how to adjust cable-operated front and rear derailleurs and is intended for general information.

**Chain Gap Adjustment (B screw)**

1. Shift the rear derailleur to the largest cog.
2. Ideally, using a chain
   gap gauge, adjust the B screw until the top derailleur jockey wheel
   aligns with the teeth of the largest cassette cog. If you do not
   have a chain gap alignment gauge handy, aim for the gap to be
   between 10-15mm* (*refer to your groupset provider)

**Rear Derailleur Adjustment**

1. Shift to the smallest cog on the rear cassette (this is the natural resting position for the derailleur when no cable tension is applied)
2. For cable operated derailleurs, remove all tension from the rear derailleur by loosening and/or removing the cable
3. Use this opportunity to wind the barrel adjuster on the rear derailleur shifter all the way in, then back it out 1 - 2 turns.
4. Adjust the high limit (H) screw so that the centre of the top pulley wheel aligns with the outboard edge of the smallest cassette cog
5. For cable operated derailleurs, re-attach the rear derailleur cable, pulling taught, but not under extreme pressure, and tighten the cable bolt.
6. Shift to the largest cog on the rear cassette
7. Adjust the low limit (L) screw so that the centre of the top pulley wheel aligns with the outboard edge of the largest cassette cog
8. Fine adjustment can now be made via the barrel adjust on the shifter

**Front Derailleur Adjustment**

1. Adjust the derailleur at its mounting bolt so that there is a clearance of 1 - 3mm between the derailleur outer plate and the largest chainring
2. Tighten the clamp bolt, but do not torque to spec
3. Shift to smallest cog on the rear cassette the largest chainring
4. Adjust the high (H) adjustment bolt and align the front end of the derailleur outer
   plate parallel to the surface of the largest chainring
5. Adjust the derailleur by rotating the mount so that the rear portion of the outer plates is 0.5 - 1mm inside the outer chainring
6. Tighten the derailleur clamp bolt and torque to spec
7. Shift to the largest cog on the rear cassette and the smallest chainring
8. Adjust the low (L) adjustment bolt so that the clearance between the skid plate of
   the derailleur and the chain is 0 - 0.5mm

[image: Shimano Dura Ace Front Derailleur]
[image: Deore XT Rear Derailleur]

Note: In the past, some mountain bike rear derailleurs worked the opposite way, i.e. they pulled cable to go to *smaller* cogs. These may have been called low-normal or Rapid Rise (a Shimano trademark) derailleurs.

Comment: Can you source the contentions in your Considerations section? I don't see how 1x necessarily provides greater gear range than a 2x - you can certainly get equivalent high and low gears on 1x and 2x, but 1x doesn't unconditionally mean a wider range. The average chainline on a 1x system could be worse than on a 2x, because your high and low gears are more cross chained. You'd do better to say that 1x should have fewer chain drops (from the front chainring(s)) on rough terrain than 2x.

Comment: A typical 11 or 12 speed cassette on a specific 1x drivetrain is as narrow, or narrower than a 10spd/11spd cassette used on 2x. In addition, the crank chainring is spaced in a manner that would that would fit where a traditional middle ring would be, eliminating cross chain even further. SRAM 1x systems typically offer a 500% gear range and I was noting that the flexibility in that range comes from not having to shift to a larger front cog.

Comment: In a 1x system's lowest gear, the chain angle is larger than in a 2x system's lowest gear, because of the change in the chainring placement that you noted.

Comment: Except, a modern rear hub on a 1x would be greater than 135mm often found on 2x systems, meaning the lowest gear is further outboard on a 142mm or 148mm hub. That would mean lowest gear would align far better with the front chainring than on a 2x system.BB shell width would also play a factor. There are too many variables to generalise that chain angle on a 1x is in any way adverse to a 2x system

Comment: If there are too many variables to generalize that a 1x system's chain angle is worse than a 2x, then I'd argue that the converse is true. One also can't argue that 1x leads to better chain angles. I have seen no literature making that statement. Also, aren't modern road bikes moving to 142mm at the rear anyway?

Comment: Exactly, decreasing chain angle further. I have a few 11spd roadbikes with 142mm rear and can quite happily ride large rear to large front with minimal rub, certainly less than a 9/10spd road bike on a 135mm rear in the same gears. There is less chain angle in this scenario. Old school Triple chainrings were offset of the chainline so that the smallest chainring could happily run almost all of the cassette without rub/wear.

Comment: Rotor makes a hydraulic groupset. Shimano also once made a pneumatically actuated one.

Answer (score 3):

### Keel Tube

Also sometimes called the "[boob tube](https://www.precisiontandems.com/artbybilltandemterms.htm)" or "[boom tube](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/gloss_i-k.html#keel)" (although ["boom" and "boom tube"](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/74190#74190) are also an unrelated part of a recumbent.)

In a tandem, the Keel Tube is approximately horizontal, and joins the front bottom bracket to the rear bottom bracket.

This part does not exist on a double-diamond bike frame.

[image: From https://www.rodbikes.com/articles/tandem-designs/direct-internal.gif]

One might consider a recumbent bicycle frame to have a keel tube as well, but generally recumbent frames have only one main tube doing all the work, so it doesn't get a special name.

Comment: @adamrice are you sure of that edit?  A quick google suggests it is many things, but not this.

Comment: That’s there only name I know it by. You should be able to find attestations.

Comment: @Criggie here is a reference for both "boob" and "boom" tube: https://www.precisiontandems.com/artbybilltandemterms.htm

Answer (score 3):

### Mudguard Stays / Fender Stays

Holders/supports to attach the mudguard/fender to the frame, as pictured.

[image]

A single stay has two legs with one on either side of the bike, and is secured to eyelets with a bolt, or bolted into a  tapped hole or rivnut.  If the frame lacks mounts it is possible to use [P clips](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/88321/6852) or zip ties, at the cost of rigidity.

Normally made of metal for durability and impact resistance.  Plastic ones exist but are uncommon.

A full rear mudguard would have two stays normally, and a front guard would have one.

Most stays have some kind of adjustment to help center the guard to avoid rub.  Older stays may need bending/straightening to achieve the same effect.  Modern stays would have breakaway features as well, to reduce injury if a body part got in the way.

See also "skirt guard"

Answer (score 3):

## Bike Chain / Roller Chain

[image: bike chain parts]

Image credit: [Park Tool](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/chain-compatibility)

A bushingless chain is made of four parts:

- A: Side Plates, a.k.a. Outer Plates
- B: Inner Plates
- C: Rivet, a.k.a. Pin
- D: Rollers

A [MasterLink](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/4483/48599) is a special kind of Side Plate, and has a "speed" rating referring to the width of chain it should be used with.

**Pitch** is the nominal distance between adjacent rollers, measured center to center. Almost all bicycle chains have 1/2" (12.7mm) pitch. Some rare exceptions tried 10mm pitch in the 1980s but you're unlikely to see those today.

**Wear/Elongation/"stretch"**  When riding, the Pins and Rollers rub against each other. Dirt getting inside the chain will accelerate wear here. As these items wear, the effective pitch of a chain increases slightly. It appears as if the chain is stretching, and this can be measured. As the chain wears, it will no longer mesh properly with the chainrings and cassette cogs, and it will accelerate wear. Thus, the chain should be replaced promptly.

For 11 speed and higher drivetrains, replacing the chain at 0.5% wear is recommended. That is, the chain appears 0.5% longer than its original length. If you replace the chain at this wear limit, the cassette will probably be okay for at least another chain. At 0.75% wear on an 11s or higher drivetrain, a new chain is likely to skip on the cassette. Much beyond this, and the chainrings may also need to be replaced. These are often more expensive than the cassette. The recommended replacement limit for 10s and earlier systems is 0.75%, and at 1% wear, the cassette often needs replacement as well.

A chain wear gauge is used to check for wear. Bike stores can check your chain, but a wear gauge is a reasonable investment for many cyclists.

**Width** Chains come in two main formats — singlespeed chain, which is 1/8" wide, and derailleur chain, which is nominally 3/32" wide but comes in many sub-widths for each speed count (more cogs = narrower chain) and is intended to flex sideways whereas singlespeed chain doesn't need to flex. For derailleur chains, it is generally recommended to use the correct speed count chain for the number of rear cogs your bicycle has.

**Bushings** Older chains sometimes had bushings between the rollers and pins, which were essentially smaller rollers made of bearing bronze. These reduced friction and slowed wear even when under-lubricated. Advances in chain metallurgy and the prospect of cheaper manufacturing result in no chains being presently available with bushings.

**Lubricants** Chains need to be cleaned and lubricated to reduce friction and wear. Lubricants are typically divided into wet and dry. Wet lubes are oil based. Dry lubes typically have wax in some sort of carrier solution; this will evaporate and should leave a chain that's mostly dry to the touch. As a more involved alternative, some cyclists wax their chains in molten paraffin wax, often with friction modifiers added.

On-bike chain cleaners can be used to clean the chain. Alternatively, one can remove the chain with the [master link](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/4483#4483), shake it in a used drink bottle with degreaser, and then reinstall it.

Contrast with **Drive Belt** and **Shaft Drive** and **Direct drive**

Comment: Regarding bushings: the current para states that chain bushings were made of bronze. It's true that bronze is used for many bushings. Was that true of chains? Bronze bushings may be run dry (I think; bronze was supposed to be self lubricating). Even bushing chains were run with lube. I would've guessed chains have always been made of steel (well, some super weight weenie chains may be titanium, but let's not go there)

Answer (score 3):

#### Stack and Reach

[image: stack and reach]
[Image credit](https://road.cc/content/feature/what-are-stack-and-reach-and-why-are-they-important-266968)

Stack is  "*The vertical distance from the centre of the bottom bracket to the central point at the top of the head tube.*" ([ref](https://road.cc/content/feature/what-are-stack-and-reach-and-why-are-they-important-266968))

Reach is "*The horizontal distance from the centre of the bottom bracket to the central point at the top of the head tube.*" ([ref](https://road.cc/content/feature/what-are-stack-and-reach-and-why-are-they-important-266968))

Comment: Stack and reach is covered under the frame sizing article. Also, this wasn’t linked in the table of contents.

Comment: @WeiwenNg ... and with even the same diagram. Still, this is an indexed list, and not everyone will think of looking under 'frame sizing' when they're searching for 'stack and reach'. An alternative (you have my blessing to go ahead and do it) is to delete this answer, but keep the index for 'stack and reach', but add a pointer saying 'look under _frame sizing \ stack and reach'.

Answer (score 2):

**REI**

*Recreational Equipment Inc* is an chain store based in the United States that specialises in outdoor goods, sporting equipment, and outdoor clothing. REI may be thought of as a mega-[LBS](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/254#254) because they have a specialist bike department and staff who ride, and bike mechanics on site. Retail store chains like Target and Walmart do not have a similar capacity.

REI is incorporated as a co-operative, in contrast to traditional for-profit retail chains. There's a one-time fee of US$20, and no renewal fee. Members are also allowed to vote for the board of directors. Membership is not required to shop in the stores.

More details at [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REI)

Company website is https://www.rei.com/

Comment: You can shop at REI even if you're not a member. you get some rewards and voting abilities if you are a member.

Answer (score 2):

**BSD (Bead Seat Diameter)**

A measure of the diameter of a wheel rim, for the purposes of tyre sizing. This is the vertical distance from the center of the hub to the shelf in the rim where the tire beads sit.

Common modern BSD sizes include 622 mm (700c road or 29er MTB), 584 mm (27.5" MTB or 650B road), and 559 mm (26" MTB). 571mm (650c wheels) is less common; it is used on some older triathlon bikes and some road bikes for smaller riders.

The European Tyre and Rim Technical Organization (ETRTO) and the International Organization for Standardization (ISO) defined this measure and how to measure it, and played some role in standardizing wheel sizes.

Answer (score 2):

### Lateral Tube (on a frame)

In a tandem, the Lateral Tube is an optional reinforcing tube that is not the top tube, the downtube, nor the keel tube.

[image: From https://www.rodbikes.com/articles/tandem-designs/direct-internal.gif]

For tandems the lateral tube is normally a single.  However a frame may have two smaller tubes, with one on each side.  This allows a continuous tube to go around the seat tube rather than two ends being welded to the seat tube.

**Variations**

Some tandems lack a Lateral tube, and simply have a quadrilateral space under the stoker.  Some have a Lateral tube and no top tube.   Some may even use a single large tube to provide an easier step-through design.

The Lateral tube has a parallel on a Mixte frame where the tube or tubes continue down to the rear axle.

[image: By Rwendland - Own work, CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=21142240]

Comment: This answer could be improved by providing the correct name for the twin tubes on the mixte frame, either as its own entry or inserted into this one.  I don't know whether they're top tubes or a pair of laterals or some other name.

Answer (score 2):

### Boom / Boom Tube

Any frame part of a bike that is in front of the head tube, excluding carriers or decks for cargo.

A Boom is almost always found on a recumbent or semi-recumbent frame where the bottom bracket is in front of the head tube.  Pictured is a Tricycle recumbent, though the same terminology applies to a two-wheeler recumbent bicycle as well.

[image: https://tadpolerider2.files.wordpress.com/2015/03/anatomy-ice-trike.jpg]

A Boom allows the frame to be adjusted for a rider's leg length.  As such, boom adjustments will almost always require a chain length adjustment unless very minor, as well as front derailleur tweaks.  A device called a "chain gobbler" can be fitted to recumbents who change riders a lot, like rentals, though they add about as much drag as a chain tensioner or derailleur.

The **Boom Tube** is normally a round, occasionally a square or profiled tube of 2-4 inches (50-100mm) diameter.  There is a slot underneath and a couple of pinch bolts, exactly like a seatpost clamp from the 80s or earlier.  A QR probably won't generate enough clamping force here.

The **Boom** itself is a T shaped tube that is just small enough to slide into the Boom Tube and be clamped onto by the pinch bolts.  At the other end is a conventional bottom bracket ready to accept a BB axle or cartridge, and a crankset.
 The boom will probably have a short 6" or 150mm stub tube that replicates the mounting for a conventional front derailleur, and may provide a mount for a front light.

The Front Derailleur control cable may be internal though the boom, or externally routed.  For booms that get adjusted a lot, an external housing makes sense.

A crank-forward bike or Semi-recumbent generally still has its cranks behind the front wheel, so does not have a boom.

Answer (score 2):

## Frame Sizing

Bicycles may have nominal sizes, e.g. extra small through extra large, or they may have a centimeter size (e.g. Specialized's road frames in 2021 have 44cm, 49cm, 52 to 58cm in 2cm increments, and 61cm). Manufacturers usually recommend a range of heights for each size.

In the past, road frames typically had equal length seat and top tubes, and their top tubes were parallel to the ground (as in the picture in the header). The frame's centimeter sizing corresponded to the length of the seat tube. Mountain bike frames had sloping top tubes (i.e. not parallel to the ground) from the beginning, and most road frames adopted a similar design. Modern road bikes' centimeter measurements do *not* typically correspond to their seat tube lengths. Frames with sloping top tubes may be called *compact frames*, and they look like the picture below.

Height ranges are an approximate guide. People can have relatively long legs for their height, or the reverse. Your local bike store will be able to help you determine the correct size in person.

### X- and Y- dimensions

If you are sizing yourself, there are two schemes to measure frame size. It is important to know how *long* the bike is (i.e. the length on the X-axis), and how *tall* it is (i.e. the Y-axis). Once you know a range of bicycle sizes in either measurement scheme that work for you, you can select potential bikes more easily. Keep in mind that you can also adjust the [stem](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index/270#270) length and its vertical height to alter the position of your handlebars.

The *effective top tube* length (diagram below) measures the former. This is what the top tube length *would be* if the bike had a level top tube; most new bikes these days have sloping top tubes, and the degree of slope can vary. The bike's *seat tube length* is the other parameter to know in this scheme. Beware that seat tube length can be measured to the center of the seat tube/top tube junction, or to the very top of the seat tube. There can be as much as a 20mm difference in length between the two types of measurement. A geometry chart will typically state if seat tube is measured center (of the bottom bracket shell) to center or center to top.

[image]

Now, manufacturers also provide stack and reach dimensions. These measure the bike's horizontal and vertical dimensions from the center of the bottom bracket to a point at the top of the head tube. This takes the seat tube angle out of the equation, discussed below.

[image]

Keep in mind that typical ranges of x- and y-dimensions for a given size will vary by bicycle discipline (e.g. endurance road bikes have lower reach and greater stack than road race bikes; many modern MTBs are designed for short stems and flat bars, so their reach dimensions will be long compared to road bikes) and by manufacturer.

### Bike design paradigms

There are systematic differences in body position among bicycle types. To some extent, they can be summarized as the ratio of stack to reach. *Performance-oriented or race-oriented* road bikes tend to favor long and low body positions. Some more leisure-oriented riders might not be able to achieve their ideal positions on a bike that is too racy. They may be better off on *endurance road bikes*, which generally favor more upright and less stretched out torso positions that are more comfortable.

Among gravel bikes, many are built like endurance road bikes. However, many also take design cues from MTB geometry. MTBs and MTB-oriented gravel bikes tend to favor relatively long top tubes and are designed for short stems. This aids handling in rough off-road terrain.

There is no shame in riding a less racy bike. Riders should seek a position that is comfortable for them, even if they are on a race bike.

---

### Secondary measures

#### Seat tube angle and seatpost setback/offset

Bicycles typically come in a small range of seat tube angles (STAs) for a given size range. Frames for average men usually have STAs around 73 degrees, with the angles steepening on smaller bike sizes and slackening on larger sizes. Some bikes, particularly mountain and triathlon bikes, may give a *virtual* STA. This is the STA *if* the bike had a straight seat tube. The steeper the STA, the further forward you sit on the bike, although remember that you can adjust your saddle position fore and aft. STA does affect the effective top tube length, but not the reach. A steeper STA pushes the whole top tube forward, so the reach would be longer.

Seatpost setback or offset describes if the saddle rail clamp is in line with the post (i.e. 0 offset or straight, commonly seen on mountain bikes), or if it is to the aft of the centerline of the seatpost (15-20mm rear offset is common on road bikes, although there may be some posts with more). Seatposts with setback position your saddle further aft by default.

Most riders *should* be able to achieve their ideal saddle fore-aft position on most combinations of STA and offset. As always, there may be exceptions for unusual body proportions and/or preferences. For example, if you prefer a very far forward position (e.g. you have short legs or you just prefer it), you may want a zero offset seatpost regardless of frame seat angle. It is possible that you may not be able to get your saddle far forward enough on some frames with slacker STAs. The reverse is true if you prefer to sit further aft; you may want to default to a setback seatpost, and avoid frames with steep STAs. Secondarily, the size of the seatpost's rail clamp can reduce the amount of fore-aft adjustment available.

Do note that STA does interact with top tube length but *not* with reach. If you fix the top tube length, a steeper STA will give you longer reach.

#### Head tube length

This affects how much vertical adjustment you can make to your handlebar position. This is less of a concern if your frame size is correct. It is possible that you might have to use excessive spacers (e.g. over 40mm, but see your bike manufacturer's guidelines) to get your handlebars high enough to be comfortable. However, if you need to do this, it may be a sign that you're on the wrong size of bike or on the wrong type of bike (e.g. you should be on a endurance road bike rather than a performance road bike).

#### Standover clearance

This is the distance from the ground to the top tube. On bikes with sloping top tubes (i.e. most of them), clearance is usually stated from the ground to the center of the top tube. When wearing cycling shoes, you can measure the distance from the floor to your crotch and compare.

In the past when road bikes had level top tubes, if you had about an inch of standover clearance, that was a potential indicator that the frame was the correct size. This is not as important as the other basic frame measures.

#### Wheel size

Almost all road bikes are sized around 700c wheels. For shorter riders, e.g. under about 5'4" or 163cm, smaller wheels like 650B or 650c may be more appropriate. The smaller stock frame sizes will tend to have more toe overlap, i.e. the front wheel can hit your foot when you turn it. This can often be adapted to, especially on road bikes when you only turn the wheels at very low speeds. However, it can also be disconcerting. Some major manufacturers offer smaller bikes in smaller wheel sizes, but not all do.

### Custom frames

Riders with body proportions significantly outside the norm may wish to consider a custom frame at some point. Many custom frames are obviously expensive, but not all are. You can ask around your local bike shop for any local framebuilders they know of, or search the internet.

### Frame geometry and handling

While this is not directly related to stack and reach, other parameters of the frame's geometry affect how it handles. A more complete discussion is [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3049/explaining-the-effects-of-frame-geometries), but frame geometry is complex. One oversimplification is that bikes can be made more stable (more effort to initiate a turn, bike tends to remain upright, easier to ride hands-free) or more agile (less effort to initiate a turn, bike feels like it dives into the turn).

Answer (score 2):

### Tolerances

Every manufacturing process has variance. That is, for each dimension specified (e.g. diameter of a bore, length of a part, how round a bearing seat is, how parallel two bearing seats are), parts will vary slightly around the mean. In engineering and manufacturing, [tolerance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_tolerance) (link to Wikipedia) is the amount by which dimensions are *allowed* to vary. That is, official specifications will show a dimension and a tolerance.

In common speech, people say a manufacturer has “poor tolerances” when they mean that a company has high variances in whatever important dimension. Poor manufacturing tolerances can cause [play](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/58543/) in components. As one example, cheap hex keys frequently fit sloppily in bolts because they may be a bit undersized.

As an example of tolerances in official specifications, the picture below is one manufacturer’s (FSA) specification for a BB386 EVO shell. The shell must be 86.50mm wide, with a symmetrical tolerance of 0.25mm. Note that tolerances can be *a*symmetric, as is the tolerance for the width of the bearing seats (46.00mm, +0mm, -0.50mm). Some manufacturers may run poorer tolerances than others, i.e. their parts have higher variance in their important dimensions. Manufacturers presumably try to catch parts that are out of tolerance, but especially in high volume production, they cannot test every single part (they likely test batches for items out of tolerance, and they may reject a whole batch and investigate if enough items were found).

[image]

### A side note: Tolerances/variances stack

In general, bottom brackets creak if they fit loosely in the frame. Tubeless tires may blow off the rim if they fit too loosely. "Too loosely" involves the tolerances of *both* the bottom bracket shell and the BB cup, or the rim and tire. That is, a brand of rim may work with many tires, but if you have a rim that's relatively small combined with a tire that's relatively large, you can have a loosely fitting tire.

Formally, the variance of the sum of two random variables (e.g. the mean diameter of a BB shell and the mean diameter of a BB cup) is the *sum* of their individual variances. Thus, the system has greater variance than a single component. (NB: technically, one also has to add 2* the *co*variance (similar to correlation) of the two quantities, but in the above scenarios the covariance can be assumed to be 0.)

Answer (score 2):

## Lights

Units that provide illumination while you ride your bike.  Energy will come via electricity in any modern light, but early lights may have been fuelled by kerosene or other combustibles.   Modern lights will be LED-based, and older ones could have an incandescent filament lamp inside.

[image: Vintage Kerosene lamp] Early liquid lights

[image: 80s Eveready lights] 1980s style, incandescent

[image: Ravemen modern LED light] Modern LED rechargable light

Most lights are detachable in some way, but a few bikes will have lights designed into the frame.  These are unusual, and will likely only be LED based.

[image: Internal lights]

---

### Seeing Lights

Bright lights for illuminating a dark road or track, for the rider's benefit.

Lights in this category are powerful enough (upwards of a thousand lumens or so) to let the rider clearly see the terrain ahead for several meters, even while riding at speed. These are best used when avoiding glare in other road users' eyes is a secondary concern, such as when mountain biking at night, or when riding on deserted roads. An analogy could be drawn to the high beams on a car. Inappropriate usage of seeing-type lights — for example on crowded roadways — can be counterproductive as other road users are likely to be dazzled by the blindingly intense light, obfuscating their vision.

### Be-Seen Lights

Smaller lights with a wider FOV so that other road users can see the rider.

Like the low beams on a car, be-seen lights are primarily intended to delineate where the bike is on the road by being *just* powerful enough to be seen without risking dazzling other road users. Their purpose is **not** to illuminate the road surface, although that may be a secondary benefit. These are best used when street lighting is adequate to spot road markings and hazards, but inadequate for other road users to easily see the cyclist. They are not recommended for off-road use as their light output may be too dim to see trail features.

### Daytime Running Light (DRL)

Physically small lights used on a bike during daylight hours, to help with being seen during the day.  Long runtime and bright output requirements means these have only been a thing since this century.  Studies have proven that cars and trucks benefit from DRLs especially in bad and marginal weather, so any road user would gain visibility by having lights.

There is not a lot of difference between a DRL and a "Be-Seen" light, other than the time of day they are in use. Laws differ by jurisdiction regarding the use of flashing or other non-steady light patterns.

[image] (a somewhat `shopped) scene of riders in a shadowed gully, with DRLs.

### Passive lights, aka Reflectors

**TBC** Unpowered passive optical devices designed to bounce light back toward a source.

Corner reflectors, Tape, increased performance over time, colours

### Rear lights

**TBC**

### Other notes

**TBC**  Batteries, Lithium/Dry cell/dynamo/other?

Flashing vs steady, and halfway-throbbing ones.  Mandates in EU about cutoff and dynamo.

Laser lines on the road.

Answer (score 2):

### Rim brake, e.g. cantilever, U- or V-brake, single or double pivot brake, side-pull brake

Brakes help you control your speed and stop. Rim brakes include all types of brakes that push pads onto a rim's brake track. [Park Tools has a page](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/rim-brake-identification) dedicated to identifying rim brake types. Rim brakes may also be called caliper brakes. Alternatively, "brake caliper" is a generic term for an item that squeezes the sides of the rim, and it houses the brake pads and bolts to an attachment on the frame. This usage stems from the measuring device, but the term is also used to refer to disc brake calipers.

Typical maintenance on rim brakes involves replacing the pads. Pads should have a wear line, and if the pad is worn to the line, it should be replaced. The pads on lower-cost rim brakes are often ineffective at braking. You can often get a noticeable improvement by switching to pads from a reputable manufacturer. Kool Stop's pads are frequently recommended. Some models of brakes have pads that slide out of holders. Other, usually cheaper, models have the pads integrated with the holders or posts, and these are replaced as a unit.

## Rim brakes for drop bar bikes: center pull, side pull, single and dual pivot

Drop bar bikes have typically mounted the front caliper in the middle of the fork crown, and the rear one in the middle of the chainstay bridge. Types have included center pull and side pull brakes. Single pivot and dual pivot brakes are types of side pull brakes, with dual pivots being stronger. Cyclocross bikes have historically used cantilever brakes, or sometimes mini-V brakes with [cable pull](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/20810/7044) suitable for road levers. Notably, road and MTB brake levers have different [cable pull ratios](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/20810/7044), so one does not typically use MTB V-brakes with a drop bar brake lever (although adapters exist).

## Rim brakes and MTBs

MTBs have used cantilever brakes, later transitioning to V-brakes, and later transitioning to disc brakes. At the time of writing, newer drop bar bikes are generally transitioning to disc brakes, although many older rim brake models exist.

In theory, rim brakes have some disadvantages to disc brakes. Rim brakes don't stop as well in wet weather, and they do eventually wear out the rims. However, they are cheaper and are a lot less sensitive to misalignment than disc brakes. Mountain bikes switched to disc brakes some time ago. Road bikes are in the process of transitioning, and in 2021, many newer bike models do not have rim braked options.

Other types of brakes include disc brakes and hub brakes, e.g. [coaster brakes](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/62698/32314).

Answer (score 2):

## Recumbent cycles

Recumbent cycles come in two, three and four wheeled versions, in many different shapes and with many different riding characteristics. The only thing they all have in common is that the 'bottom bracket' is not low down between the wheels but farther forward and farther up.
The sitting position is almost never bend over forward but can be anything from straight up to almost flat back, although some people will only call a cycle a recumbent if the seatback leans back by at least a given angle. Colloquially, recumbent bikes may be called "bent bikes" or "bents", and recumbent cyclists may refer to upright bikes as "wedgies."

Steering can several different ways, most commonly called above seat steering and underseat steering, can be direct or with a rod or more advanced ways as dictated by the geometry of the cycle and the wishes of the builder.

Because of the basic position, not needing to lean on your arms while riding, and the wide variations in models and options, recumbents are often adjusted for use by people who have some limitations. That goes from moving the brake leavers to be on the same side, to replacing the bottom bracket with cranks and pedals to a hand driven power system.
Trikes are more often adjusted as they allow for more limitations, like loss of balance or loss of the use of one arm or leg.

More information in this [Wikipedia article.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recumbent_bicycle)

[image: Flevotrike]
This is a Flevotrike which has underseat handlebars but an unusual steering method, in which there is a pivot point under the seat and the whole of the front, including the front wheel drive, tilts. Photo by me, trike owned by me.

[Boom tubes](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/74190/38270) are frequently found on recumbents but not on upright bikes. [Velomobiles](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/81885/19705) are a class of recumbent bike enclosed by a fairing.

Comment: I can imagine a one-wheeled recumbent, briefly, as a unicycle transitions from vertical to horizontal !

Comment: I have recently seen a photo of a  one wheel motorcycle, where rider and motor are within the huge wheel. I can see one such in recumbent cycle riding position but have never seen nor heard about one wheel 'bents.

Answer (score 2):

### Cassette

A stack of cogs on the rear axis to provide changeable gears. It is held on a hub by the threaded lockring.

[image: Cassette next to freehub]

Cassette next to the hub ([image credit](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cassetteandfreehub.jpg)).

The cogs may be separable or more often some or all are riveted together for convenience. A few smallest (fastest gears) cogs are more often separable; they wear faster than others and this way can be replaced individually. The smallest cog may cost a tenth of the price of the complete cassette or even less.

Cassettes designed for different number of gears (cogs) often have different spacing between cogs and generally cannot be swapped. Different vendors are usually not compatible. There are exceptions like all Shimano cassettes up to 7 cogs inclusive have the same spacing. In some cases compatibility can be achieved with additional spacers. More about the compatibility can be found [here](https://bike.bikegremlin.com/1232/bicycle-cassette-compatibility/).

The modern derailleur moves not just along the rear axis but also diagonally. Due this, there is both **minimal** and **maximal** limit for the number of teeth on **both** smallest and largest cog. You cannot just pick a cassette that fits your life style the best.

The cassette can be easily unscrewed from the wheel with two specialized tools, the "park tool" (a wrench for the lockring) and the "chain whip" (see the picture below).

[image: Chain whip]

Chain whip ([image credit](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Track_sprocket_tool_by_Bruce_McAdam.jpg)).

The whip holds the cassette in place, otherwise it would rotate even if you hold the wheel, because freewheel would allow in this direction. The chain whip may be gear number specific (because the chain on it is), or for a limited speed range. It is not required for putting the cassette back onto the wheel because the freewheel mechanism blocks the rotation in this direction. The lockring must be quite strongly tightened (40 Nm).

The park tool may be vendor specific (true for Campagnolo) or multiple vendors may support the same standard (often Shimano). Many are designed for a usage with the external wrench ([23.4mm](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07D7G2SFH)), others have they own handle.

[image]

The park tool ([image credit](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/43499/is-this-an-unsuitable-cassette-lockring-tool), edited).

With the suitable chain whip, park tool and matching cassette, the replacement is actually easy (replacing tire is more work). The axis of the modern freewheel only accepts cogs in one exact orientation so these cannot be placed wrongly. Spacing between cogs of the assembled cassette must be the same for all cogs. If not, likely a spacer between cogs is missing or in a wrong place.

Cassettes serve less than a bicycle in general and are replaced when worn. The worn cogs start skipping under load, this cannot be fixed by adjusting any screws and putting a new chain at this time actually worsens the problem. When very worn, some cogs just skip with no traction, but makes sense to replace earlier. Worn teeth are visually recognizable from they shape when they were new. Worn cassette also significantly reduces life of a new chain if put in this combination.

Answer (score 2):

## Potts Mod

This is a brake cable layout design done primarily on BMX bikes, combined with a [Detangler](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/82978/19705) that allows the front wheel and handlebars to spin 360 degrees without getting stopped by wires and cables.

This dates from the 80s, and was originally done by Steve Potts, hence the name.

Since BMXs are mostly singlespeed, there are no gear cables involved.

Instead, the front brake cable outer runs down through the hollow steerer tube of the fork and therefore through the headset bearings.

[image: ""]
White outer cable passing through a hole in the top of a BMX stem. Look closely and you can see the hole is through the middle of the stem bolt, which has an external hex drive instead of an internal one, and so has to be exposed and not recessed.  The quill stem bold goes down inside the steerer tube and the access hole goes right through, so the bolt needs to be sufficiently strong despite being hollow.

[image: ""] 
Same outer cable drops out the bottom of the fork crown, just above the tyre, and is well-secured to one fork-leg.

[image: ""] 
Lastly, the cable loops back up to the front brake.  Yes, this cable is excessively long and risks catching on things, but I intend on redoing it with black outer which is harder to photograph.

You would generally find this done with U brakes as pictured, or traditional caliper brakes rearranged to have the cable enter from below, not above.

A race BMX would not need this - instead it would be a Freestyle or Trick BMX used for stunts or performances.  This bike is also equipped with [Foot-Pegs](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/82982/19705) and a [Detangler](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/82978/19705)

Note these photos show a Diamondback BMX that has these features built into the design from new.  This change was originally a literal modification, and was the only change needed to allow for barspins, when the bikes have a coaster/backpedal brake.

Downside:  The downward loop of outer cable holds moisture and will rust out faster than normal.  Ideally your brake cable would have an exit at the lowest point and could not hold water for long periods.

Links: https://bmxmuseum.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=56527

Answer (score 2):

## Detangler / Rotor / Spinner / Gyro

Closely connected to the [Potts Mod](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/82978/19705)  this is a brake setup that allows a BMX's handlebars to rotate 360 degrees without wrapping the rear brake cable around the headset of the bike.

Almost completely exclusive to Trick BMXs, this is not something that would be on a racing BMX.

[image: ""]  The rear brake lever is conventional, but the cabling passes through a splitter.  This gives two brake internal cables which are linked to the detangler.

[image: ""] The detangler is two separate metal rings with tabs, secured together with a thin ball bearing that goes around the stem/headset.  As the bars turn, the bearing operates, letting the top metal ring stay in line with the bars, while the bottom ring stays with the bike.

When the rider pulls the rear brake lever, both sides of the detangler lift, which pulls the next two wires.  This avoids the detangler from going off-horizontal and binding which would stop the brake from working.

Not pictured is a down-stream splitter in reverse, that recombines both wires and has a single cable coming out to actuate the rear brake.

Downsides, this system adds weight, and also introduces flex so the rear brake is less snappy.  There are three more metal parts which could tap on the frame making noise.  The bearing is relatively poorly-protected too.

---

Note: This is nothing to do with a disk brake Rotor, which is defined  elsewhere.

---

After writing this, I disassembled the brake planning to replace ~6 brake cables and many segments of outer and ferrules.   Surprisingly, the cable set is not standard with the splitter/combiner acting to clamp normal inners; instead the top and bottom Y shapes are one unit each.

[image: ""]  As you can see the two wires really are permanently secured to the single wire.   So a replacement rear brake cable set for a BMX with a detangler is a specialist item.

Answer (score 2):

## Foot Pegs or Pegs

These are axle extensions that allow a trick BMX rider to stand or hold onto the bike in additional places.  They can also be used for grinding/sliding tricks.

[image: ""]

Solely the domain of stunt BMXs - you'd never see these on anything else.

To release the normal process is a screwdriver through two opposing holes and simply unthread.

[image: ""]

Each peg is essentially an elongated nut that screws over an exposed length of the bike's axle.  As such, it is possible to overload the peg and bend the end of the axle making removal difficult.  A loose peg is also more likely to damage threads so make sure they're tight.

Pegs are almost always made from steel, though plastic ones may be coming.  The outside is frequently knurled or textured for grip on a shoe's sole, but can also slide on a metal fixture like this:

[image: https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5bf26b8bdf7c09f5752d8b38/5bf27d5760911a5089560000_bike%20peg.jpg]

Answer (score 2):

#### Over Locknut Dimension, abbreviated O.L.D. or OLD.

[image: axle, cones, and locknuts]

O.L.D. refers not to the length (width in the image) of the axle, but to the distance between the outer surface of the two locknuts.

Due to the lack of standardization for cups and cones, replacing just a cone is difficult. It is considerably easier to match the Over Locknut Dimensions (O.L.D.) and the diameter of the axle. If these two dimensions are matched, then any cone with curvature vaguely resembling the old cone will likely be fine.

---

Similarly, the Over Locknut Dimension has to match the frame into which the wheel will be installed.

[image: https://cdn-0.sheldonbrown.com/images/measure-spacing.jpg] 
 from https://www.sheldonbrown.com/frame-spacing.html, showing a 126mm OLD frame.

OLD of a frame can be tweaked under some circumstances, but not by much and the frame has to be steel. 126mm to 130 would be fine, and 130 to 135, but 126 up to 135 would be stressing the frame too much.  You might need to re-align the dropouts afterward.  Never do this with aluminium or carbon frames.

OLD of a wheel can often be adjusted by adding/removing spacers, and swapping spacers from side to side.

Common OLD measurements may be found at https://www.sheldonbrown.com/frame-spacing.html

Answer (score 2):

#### Actuation Ratio

When a mechanical gear shifter is moved by the rider's hand, it will pull a fixed amount of inner gear wide through the outer.  The shifter at the other end will move (actuate) a certain amount, which will be different.

Naturally there are many standards, along with exceptions to standards.  In brief:

Shimano  6/7/8/9 - Rear shift ratio is **1.7** so for 1 mm of cable, the Rear Deraileur moves left/right by 1.7 mm 
 Shimano calls this 2:1 ratio for marketing reasons.

All these RDs are compatible and any 6 to 9 speed RD will work perfectly with either 6, 7, 8 or 9 speed shifter assuming it can physically span the width of the cassette.  Regardless whether it’s a MTB, or road shifter, or RD. They are also compatible with Shimano 10 speed road shifters (except the Tiagra 4700 series)

| Name | Ratio |
| --- | --- |
| Shimano standard 6/7/8/9 speed and 10 speed Road excluding Tiagra | 1.7x |
| Shimano Dura Ace 6 to 8 speeds (vintage stuff) | 1.9x |
| SRAM 2:1 | 1.7x |
| Campagnolo old | 1.4x |
| Shimano 10 MTB | 1.2x |
| SRAM 1:1 | 1.1x |
| Campagnolo new | 1.5x |
| Shimano 11 road and Tiagra 10 speed 4700 | 1.4x |
| SRAM Exact Actuation | 1.3x |
| Shimano 11 MTB | 1.1x |
| SRAM X-Actuation 11-speeds | 1.12x |
| SRAM X-Actuation 12-speeds | 1.01x |

Note that Shimano Internally Geared Hubs (Nexus and Alfine) do not have equal pull distances, so adjacent clicks are NOT the same length.  These shifters are incompatible with derailleur gears, and the IGHs do NOT work with normal shifters.

Further info:

- [Are rear derailleur cable intervals equal?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/67895/are-rear-derailleur-cable-intervals-equal)
- https://bike.bikegremlin.com/1278/bicycle-rear-derailleur-compatibility/

Answer (score 2):

#### Chainline

*Chainline* is the [relationship](https://youtu.be/0lN3Zf9gpp8) of the sprockets to the centerline of the bike.

##### Front Chainline

On a 1x system, the *front chainline* is the perpendicular distance from the chainring to the center plane of the bicycle.

On a 2x system, measure the distance from the middle of the two chainrings.

On a 3x system, measure from the center chainring.

##### Rear Chainline

The *rear chainline* is the perpendicular distance from the middle sprocket (among an odd number of sprockets) to the center plane of the bicycle. For even sprockets use half the distance between the middle two sprockets.

Answer (score 2):

## **Dutch Bike**

Synonymous with:  **utility bicycle, city bicycle, urban bicycle, European city bike (ECB),  classic bike** or simply **city-bike**

[image]

Dutch bikes are designed for every day use in rain and shine, for short-distance commuting, running errands, shopping, leisure  and known for their often minimal features, rugged reliability and upright riding position.

Classic design features are:

- features to keep the riders (regular) clothes clean of mud/oil/snow/dirt and prevent them from catching on the chain or in the spokes:

  - fully enclosed enclosed [chain guard](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/21177#21177)
  - skirt/coat guards
  - front and rear [fenders/mudguards](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/2803#2803)
- clean and rugged design:
  No features that are easily damaged in crowded bike parks,
  and omit features that require regular maintenance:

  - no external brake cables and/or brake levers on the handlebar but instead:

    [coaster brakes](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/62698#62698)
  - no [derailleur](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/64473#64473), external shift cables and shifters but rather:

    single speed
  - fully enclosed enclosed [chain guard](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/21177#21177) to keep the chain clean and protected from weather and dirt.
- front and/or rear [luggage carrier](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/1862#1862)
- fixed front and rear lights powered by a dynamo
- Single, dual or adjustable kickstand
- O-lock
- curved and (slightly) elevated [handlebar](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/322#322) facilitating the upright riding position.

Common standard improvements and upgrades are:

- Improved brakes, i.e. disc or [rim brakes](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/81822#81822) instead of or in addition to the [coaster brakes](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/62698#62698)
- Additional gears, typically with an [internally geared hub](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/1728#1728) to keep it low maintenance
- [hub dynamo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hub_dynamo) rather than a rim dynamo
- belt drive rather than chain (relatively expensive and still not too common)

In comparison a **commuter bike** is designed for longer rides and typically offers more gears, associated more powerful brakes, suspension and a less upright and more active and dynamic riding position.

Answer (score 2):

### R-clip or P-clip

These are the clips that attach the [fender stays](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/81592/6852) to the frame. Both metal and plastic clips are used.

These should clamp down firmly on the stay because they are providing structural support.  Rubber-lined ones are more intended for supporting wires loosely, which is wrong here.

Stays come in different thicknesses; check yours before buying.  Use threadlocker on the bolts too.

[image: Rear Derailleur area]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

### MIPS helmet

A helmet with a low friction layer that allows the helmet to slide relative to the head following an angled impact. This is thought to reduce the rotational motion of the head during an impact, especially during an oblique impact. Previous helmets were not designed to protect against this type of acceleration. In theory, reducing the amount of rotational acceleration should reduce the damage to the brain. Our community have discussed MIPS [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32719/are-mips-helmets-actually-any-safer-than-standard-helmets-independent-research) and [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/77213/how-important-is-the-mips-safety-system-for-a-bicycle-helmet). In summary, lab tests do show that MIPS helmets reduce the amount of angular or rotational acceleration in the test setup. However, lab tests cannot precisely replicate real-world conditions, and it is impossible to do real-world randomized experiments comparing MIPS to non-MIPS helmets.

Answer (score 1):

### Velomobiles

A special class of recumbent cycles is fully faired, mostly three wheeled (although there are four wheeled versions as well) called [Velomobiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velomobile), although many people may know them by different names.

The main advantage of a velomobile is higher speed for the same effort, but it comes at the price of being lower and therefor less visible on the road, paying more for the machine and often a bigger turning cicle.

[image: Yellow Quest with blue details]
My own Velomobile, a Quest, here parked in Beverwijk, the Netherlands.

There are also two wheeled fully faired cycles, but as far as I know those are not classed as velomobiles, they are the fastest that is out in man powered vehicles, whether single rider or a team of riders. [This is a link to a magazine like internet page, a few years old, of an event which gets the fastest cycles.](https://nevadagram.com/a-visit-to-battle-mountain-during-hpv-speed-challenge-2/)

Answer (score 1):

## Boot, Tyre Boot

A firm but flexible piece of anything that can be inserted between a tyre and a tube, to provide additional support at a damaged point.  If the tyre is cut, gashed, or torn to the point your tube is visible, it will puncture again in short order, and that puncture is likely to be explosive not gradual.

[image]
 from [Rear Tyre torn at rim - what was the cause?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/47929/rear-tyre-torn-at-rim-what-was-the-cause)

Also, small holes in the tread can give punctures too, as the tube bulges out and wears off on the road surface.

---

Park makes a boot, called the TB-2 which is similar to an oversized sticker pre-glued tube patch, but is intended to stick to the inner wall of the tyre.

However the enterprising cyclist can use many different items as a boot.

- An empty gel wrapper is a common choice (but clean it well, the content will go everywhere even if you think it is empty!)
- If your country uses polymer banknotes they can work, but not paper notes,
- Any item of flexible plastic from your tools
- Strips of duct tape

Tubeless tyres might benefit from a boot, if the damage is too large for the sealant to plug.  However it could be hard to get the boot to lie in the right place for long enough.

Relevant questions: [What's the point of tyre boots?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/81922/)