# triathlon beginners guide

Tags: beginner, triathlon

I'm new to triathlon and want to ask about what are bikes that consider a good choice for triathlon beginners? for both training and locale or small competitions.

Here are some parameters to put in mind while recommending bikes:

1. Price range: As a beginner, I may give up early if I find out that this sport is not suitable for me, and spending $10k on a bike at this stage is not the best decision for sure.
2. Durability: beginners usually do mistakes, and may broke their bikes. A durable bike is highly recommended for this stage, right?
3. Ease of use: I mean by use; easy to be assembled, disassembled and any common or periodical fixes that need to be done to the bike.

Any other suggestions to put in consideration, please add.

Comment: Many triathlon specific bikes are twitchy and difficult for beginners. You might be better off getting a road bike, which will probably be more stable, cheaper, and fast enough for a beginner.

Comment: @Kibbee Thanks for the advice. Can you be more specific about which models of road bikes is good based on the above parameters? and what other parameters would you recommend a beginner to look for in the bike before buying?

Comment: You'll want to try out the bikes and take them for a good test ride.  You'll be able to tell which ones are twitchy when you're riding them.  In general, a longer wheel base, lower bottom bracket, and more fork rake (distance the  fork is ahead of the steering axis) will equate to a more stable bike.

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are close to off-topic because they [tend to become obsolete quickly](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), therefore it might get closed. Maybe you want to focus a bit more on asking what features you should look for than on specific product recommendations. @Kibbee already pointed you a bit into this direction.

Comment: Any quality road bike is going to be sufficient for your first few triathlons. If it stands up to your training rides, it'll be fine on the triathlon itself. People ride all sorts of bikes in triathlons, including hybrids and mountain bikes. Focus more on what you're going to be comfortable riding for training than on what you think you'll need for a race because you'll be doing 10 times more training rides than races. Just visit a local bike shop, give them your price range and goals and they'll fit you up with the best bike in your price range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Budget advice**
Visit/Join a Tri Club and check out what second-hand bikes the members are selling. Aim for the low end, say less than $1000. Make sure you ride a few different bikes so that you can compare.

- It needs to be comfortable and fit well.
- It must have quick-release wheels.

Also, work out what shoes and pedals you are comfortable using: will you use [toe clips or clipless](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/240/why-the-heck-are-cleated-shoes-called-clipless/242#242)?

**Serious Advice**
Find a local Tri shop or LBS and talk it over with them. Be firm about your budget, and that it includes clothes, shoes, and pedals. A good shop will let you ride the bike before you buy, provide some free service and fit the bike to you. Shop around as well. Be up front with the staff: tell them that you are starting and are checking out your options.

Good luck!

Comment: This, together with @Kibbee's advice in the comments should get the OP going. Another good hint: NOW is the season to buy a road bike -- this year's models are discounted quite a bit while next year's models are not yet on sale.